# How to test the response code with Capybara + Selenium

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, rspec, capybara

I have the following spec:

```
it "deletes post", :js => true do 
...
...
page.status_code.should = '404'

end
```

The `page.status_code` line is giving me this error:

```
Capybara::NotSupportedByDriverError
```

How do I check the page's status code?

Comment: related: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/ruby-capybara/KdMvhjcjm8E

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get HTTP Response Code using Selenium WebDriver with Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6509628/how-to-get-http-response-code-using-selenium-webdriver-with-java)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`status_code` is not currently supported by the Selenium driver. You will need to write a different test to check the response status code.

Answer (score 48):

As an aside. This line

```
page.status_code.should = '404'
```

Should be

```
page.status_code.should == 404
```

This worked for me with capybara-webkit.

Comment: another capybara-webkit user is here but `expect(page.status_code).to be(200)` returns `Capybara::NotSupportedByDriverError`. Do you have any idea why?

Answer (score 3):

Either switch to another driver (like `rack-test`) for that test, or test that the displayed page is the 404 page (should have content 'Not Found' in h1).

As @eugen said, Selenium doesn't support status codes.

Answer (score 3):

Selenium web driver doest not implement status_code and there is no direct way to test response_code with selenium (developer's choice).

To test it I added in my layout/application.html.erb:

```
<html code="<%= response.try(:code) if defined?(response) %>">[...]</html>
```

And then in my test:

```
def no_error?
  response_code = page.first('html')[:code]
  assert (response_code == '200'), "Response code should be 200 : got #{response_code}"
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Try it out

```
expect(page).to have_http_status(200)
```

Comment: Hi Ajay; your code might be correct, but with some context it would make a better answer; for example, you could explain how and why this proposed change would resolve the questioner's problem, perhaps including a link to the relevant documentation. That would make it more useful to them, and also more useful to other site readers who are looking for solutions to similar problems.

Comment: I get `expected #<Capybara::Session:0x00007fabb8a439e8> to respond to 'has_http_status?' (RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError)`

Comment: Note: This isn't provided by `Capybara`, but by `RSpec`.
https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/matchers/have-http-status-matcher

Answer (score 0):

Use js to make a request and get status as below:

```
js_script = <<JSS
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', '#{src}', true);
xhr.send();
JSS
actual.execute_script(js_script)
status = actual.evaluate_script('xhr.status') # get js variable value
```

Check https://gist.github.com/yovasx2/1c767114f2e003474a546c89ab4f90db for more details

Answer (score 0):

```rb
expect(page).to have_http_status(:ok)
```

is an acceptable variation to [Ajay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6119493/ajay)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40887611/7573223), if you prefer the status symbol over the code value, for readability.

References:

- https://rubydoc.info/gems/rack/Rack/Utils
- https://gist.github.com/mlanett/a31c340b132ddefa9cca

For all available status codes / symbols:

```rb
Rack::Utils::SYMBOL_TO_STATUS_CODE
       # or 
Rack::Utils::HTTP_STATUS_CODES
```