# How to capture all requests made by page in webdriver? Is there any alternative to Browsermob?

Tags: java, selenium, proxy, webdriver, har

I am using Selenium2/WebDriver to test my web applications. All the tests are written in Java and run with Maven.

While opening a page with webdriver I'd like to capture all the requests made by page (images, js and css files, etc). I use this data mainly for two reasons

- checking for 404 (and other errors) in calls
- checking if analytics code is working (checking if it's sending proper requests)

Depending on the project I use either Firebug with Netexport or Browsermob proxy. In both cases I can easily obtain a HAR (Html ARchive) file, parse it and extract the data I want.

Here's the problem:
I am not happy with neither of these solutions. I have especially problems with getting HAR file when a page contains video that is being loaded too long. I am looking for something more stable.

So, the questions are:

Is there any alternative to Browsermob? I know about FiddlerCore but it's a .NET library and my tests are written in Java. I've also heard about Ajax DynaTrace and I know that there is some way to integrate it with Selenium but the documentation I found was for Selenium-RC not WebDriver.

Is there any way to integrate DynaTrace with WebDriver or use FiddlerCore with Java?

Is there any other way to achieve the goals I mentioned? I am looking for a proxy that I can easily control from my code. Exporting data to HAR would be a great plus.

Comment: You can use create a C# webservice and call it from java

Comment: This question is not the same but quite equals to: "How to get HTTP Response Code using Selenium WebDriver" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6509628/how-to-get-http-response-code-using-selenium-webdriver/51919201#51919201

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found a google groups discussion [on the topic](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/webdriver/L07NvliQZRk). These links look like promising alternative to Browsermob:

- [A Selenium CaptureNetworkTraffic Example in Java](http://blog.eviltester.com/2010/05/a-selenium-capturenetworktraffic-example-in-java.html)
- [HOWTO: Collect WebDriver HTTP Request and Response Headers](http://www.supermind.org/blog/968/howto-collect-webdriver-http-request-and-response-headers)
- [Automating the Capture of Web Timings with Selenium 2](http://www.theautomatedtester.co.uk/blog/2010/selenium-webtimings-api.html)

Answer (score 5):

There is an alternative with firefox ver 42+, there is addon called Firefox HarExport

```
File harExportApi = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")
                     + "/src/main/resources/firebug/harexporttrigger-0.5.0-beta.7.xpi");

netExportProfile.addExtension(harExportApi);
netExportProfile.setPreference("extensions.netmonitor.har.enableAutomation", true);
    netExportProfile.setPreference("extensions.netmonitor.har.contentAPIToken", "test");
    netExportProfile.setPreference("extensions.netmonitor.har.autoConnect", true);

cap.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, netExportProfile);
```

and running following script will give us all the request responses

```
 String getHarLogScript = "var options = {\n" +
                "    token: \"test\",\n" +
                "    getData: true,\n" +
                "    title: \"my custom title\",\n" +
                "    jsonp: false,\n" +
                "  };\n" +
                "\n" +
                "  HAR.triggerExport(options).then(result => {\n" +
                "    var har = JSON.parse(result.data);\n" +
                "\n" +
                "    // Use performance.timing to provide onContentLoad\n" +
                "    +
                "     +
                "    var t = performance.timing;\n" +
                "    var pageTimings = har.log.pages[0].pageTimings;\n" +
                "    pageTimings.onContentLoad = t.domContentLoadedEventStart - t.navigationStart;\n" +
                "    pageTimings.onLoad = t.loadEventStart - t.navigationStart;\n" +
                "\n" +
                "    window.HarEntries=har.log.entries\n" +
                "\n" +
                "    console.log(\"HAR log (\" + result.data.length + \") \", har.log);\n" +
                "  }, err => {\n" +
                "    console.error(err);\n" +
                "  });"

LOG.info("Loading HAR log entries object into browser HarEntries object");
SeleniumUtils.executeScript(driver, getHarLogScript);

harEntries = ((List<Object>) SeleniumUtils.executeScript(driver, "return window.HarEntries"));
```

Comment: I tried the above code. it says ~org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: ReferenceError: HAR is not defined~ How do i include this dependency. Selenium3.0.0, FF 51, Mac OS.

Answer (score 3):

I've been working recently on this kind of proxy. Project is pretty fresh, I'm still working on documentation but it may be worth checking. Sources and examples are [here](https://github.com/lukasz-aw/moxproxy)

1. Add dependency to your project

```
    <dependency>
       <groupId>com.moxproxy</groupId>
       <artifactId>moxproxy.core</artifactId>
       <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

2. Start proxy

```
    MoxProxy proxy = LocalMoxProxy.builder()
                .withPort(89)
                .build();
    proxy.startServer();
```

3. Setup selenium webdriver to use proxy on localhost with port 89 and run test
4. Collect traffic

```
    List<MoxProxyProcessedTrafficEntry> requestTraffic = proxy.getAllRequestTraffic();
    List<MoxProxyProcessedTrafficEntry> responseTraffic = proxy.getAllResponseTraffic();
```

Beside collecting traffic proxy provides posibility to modify requests and responses - details on [github](https://github.com/lukasz-aw/moxproxy/blob/master/moxproxy.local.examples/src/test/java/testing/e2e/LocalProxyTest.java)