# Java Selenium: how to read Network tab output during the test run?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Is there anyway to capture what is streaming in Network tab during test run?
I need to verify that server send the particular response which is visible in Network tab. I need it to verify that based on response, the particular UI is displayed. 
Thank you so much for any hint.
gala

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to proxy your WebDriver browser. Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20899331/need-to-capture-network-traffic-using-proxy-in-selenium-webdriver-code).

Alternatively you could use [ZAP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Zed_Attack_Proxy_Project). This is a [sample](https://github.com/continuumsecurity/zap-webdriver) setup with Selenium WebDriver, but it might be an overkill.