# Is there any way, we can get the sent http request details in java code?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am working on java with selenium web driver and we are writing script for .Net web application. However, the script is working fine but the things is we need to fetch the details from browser to get http sent request and response of request. For example: Auto-complete drop down, click functionality, etc., Let assume that I have type selenium in google text box, so here system will display auto complete drop down with list of options. Now, what we want is when we type 'Selenium' obviously system sent request to server - we need this details in java code for sent request as soon as browser sent it and response details that is list of drop down from server. Is this possible? to get such details in java code using selenium?

Thanks in advance,
Dani

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10755480/how-to-capture-all-requests-made-by-page-in-webdriver-is-there-any-alternative

Comment: Thanks, for your response and link. I think I will get lots of information from above link.