# Force Selenium Chrome Driver to use QUIC instead of TCP

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver, browsermob-proxy, quic

I am working on downloading HAR from Chrome for YouTube through Selenium Python Script.
Code Snippet:

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--proxy-server={0}".format(url))
chrome_options.add_argument("--enable-quic")

self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver,chrome_options = chrome_options)

self.proxy.new_har(args['url'], options={'captureHeaders': True})
self.driver.get(args['url'])
result = json.dumps(self.proxy.har, ensure_ascii=False)
```

I want QUIC to be used whenever I download HAR but when I look at the packets through Wireshark Selenium driver is using TCP only. Is there a way to force Chrome Driver to use QUIC? Or Is there an alternate to BMP?

A similar thing has been asked for Firefox in this question [How to capture all requests made by page in webdriver? Is there any alternative to Browsermob?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10755480/how-to-capture-all-requests-made-by-page-in-webdriver-is-there-any-alternative/40322699#40322699) and there was a solution with Selenium alone without need of any BMP. So is it possible for Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

Workaround for this problem could be: start Chrome normally (with your default profile or create another profile) and enable quic manually. Then start chromedriver with your profile loaded.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=/home/user/.config/google-chrome")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/home/user/Downloads/chromedriver", chrome_options=options)
```