# How to fix "Could not read Browsermob-Proxy json"?

Tags: selenium, browsermob-proxy

I am trying to use `browsermob-proxy` to monitor all requests and responses for selenium tests. In my case, I am running the `selenium` tests with the `py.test` framework inside a `docker` image on `jenkins`. I am using the following versions:

- selenium==3.8.0
- pyvirtualdisplay==0.2.1
- pytest==3.4.0
- browsermob-proxy==0.8.0

also java `openjdk-8-jdk`.

Inside the `py.test` code I have the following line to create and start the server:

```
proxyserver =  Server(
           path="/root/tests/bsp_usecase_tests/bin/browsermob-proxy",
           options={'port': 8090}
       )
proxyserver.start()
driverproxy = proxyserver.create_proxy() # line 127
```

but in the last line I get the following error:

```
conftest.py:127: in basedriver
    driverproxy = proxyserver.create_proxy()
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/browsermobproxy/server.py:40: in create_proxy
    client = Client(self.url[7:], params)
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 

self = <browsermobproxy.client.Client object at 0x7f1a5f73f1d0>
url = 'localhost:8090', params = {}, options = {}

    def __init__(self, url, params=None, options=None):
        """
            Initialises a new Client object


            :param url: This is where the BrowserMob Proxy lives
            :param params: URL query (for example httpProxy and httpsProxy vars)
            :param options: Dictionary that can contain the port of an existing
                            proxy to use (for example 'existing_proxy_port_to_use')
            """
        params = params if params is not None else {}
        options = options if options is not None else {}
        self.host = "http://" + url
        if params:
            urlparams = "?" + unquote(urlencode(params))
        else:
            urlparams = ""
        if 'existing_proxy_port_to_use' in options:
            self.port = options['existing_proxy_port_to_use']
        else:
            resp = requests.post('%s/proxy' % self.host + urlparams)
            content = resp.content.decode('utf-8')
            try:
                jcontent = json.loads(content)
            except Exception as e:
                raise Exception("Could not read Browsermob-Proxy json\n"
>                               "Another server running on this port?\n%s..." % content[:512])
E               Exception: Could not read Browsermob-Proxy json
E               Another server running on this port?
E               <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
E               <html><head>
E               <meta type="copyright" content="Copyright (C) 1996-2016 The Squid Software Foundation and contributors">
E               <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=utf-8">
E               <title>ERROR: The requested URL could not be retrieved</title>
E               <style type="text/css"><!-- 
E                /*
E                * Copyright (C) 1996-2016 The Squid Software Foundation and contributors
E                *
E                * Squid software is distributed under GPLv2+ license and incl...

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/browsermobproxy/client.py:37: Exception
```

Maybe I forgot to copy important files into the docker image?

I have the following setup for the `browsermob-proxy` (besides the pip install):

```
bsp_usecase_tests/bin:
browsermob-proxy

bsp_usecase_tests/lib:
browsermob-dist-2.1.4.jar
```

i.e. I have copied the file `browsermob-proxy` into `bin` and the file `browsermob-dist-2.1.4.jar` into the `lib` folder. Also, the server itself seem to be starting and running. But I get this weird error when I try to get the proxy information I can use for the selenium driver...

Any ideas what I have done wrong, or what is missing?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that the port is already in use. You can check if the port is being used using `lsof` and then kill it, if it is in use. You can check using `lsof -i:8090`

EDIT :
And you have already done that in this thread - 
[How to fix 'Address already in use' error with browsermob-proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48315438/how-to-fix-address-already-in-use-error-with-browsermob-proxy)

I would initialize server with

```
proxyserver =  Server(
       path="/root/tests/bsp_usecase_tests/bin/browsermob-proxy",
       options={'existing_proxy_port_to_use': 8090})
```

This should do it.

The internal code in Browsermob-Proxy is looking for key in `'options'` dictionary named `'existing_proxy_port_to_use'`, else it uses default i.e. empty dictionary.

Comment: I have tried both options, `options={'existing_proxy_port_to_use': 8090}` and `options={'port':8090}`, and in both cases I get the exact same error message...

The problem is not that easy I am afraid...

Comment: In your error console, can you share the next line to this
self = <browsermobproxy.client.Client object at 0x........>
 after you tried the existing_proxy_port_to_use

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. What error console? Remember that I am running all of the code inside a docker image...

Comment: Ha, I mean the error that you get when using existing_proxy_port_to_use': 8090', can you post that, it feels redundant but I would like to see if it made any difference

Comment: I just looked at the source code for broswermob-proxy (the python wrapper), and the only thing the implementation is checking in the options is a possible key `port`, nothing else (https://github.com/AutomatedTester/browsermob-proxy-py/blob/master/browsermobproxy/server.py). Also it looks like I have an somewhat older installation.

Comment: Otherwise the complete error here: https://gist.github.com/alex4200/bab5063b68c9e2362b4d683d50fa3159

Comment: I see, the option you mentioned is in the `Client` package. I will try to call the Client directly...

Comment: I think the problem was really that processes used these ports. I am not sure I can reproduce the problem anymore. 

Suggestion: Either restart computer or investigate the processes that use the ports...