# How do I set header when using browsermob proxy selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, browsermob-proxy, browsermob, seleniumwire

I am having troubles setting a custom header when using `browsermob proxy` with `selenium`. I only see examples using `Java`, but none for `Python`. I want to know how to do so using `browsermob proxy` and `Selenium-wire`, and the difference/use cases between both.

If I can get an implementation of both (using `Python` and `ChromeOptions`) in one answer that would be great.

I have installed bmp and set it up following this post:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/48266639/18346591

My current code looks like this

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from collections import Counter
from browsermobproxy import Server

server = Server('C:\\Users\\HP\\Documents\\browsermob-proxy-2.1.4-bin\\bin\\browsermob-proxy')
server.start()
proxy = server.create_proxy()
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--proxy-server={0}".format(proxy.proxy))
options.add_experimental_option('detach', True)
options.add_argument("--disable-proxy-certificate-handler")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

I am not trying to add a proxy. At least not yet. I just got a bit confused.

Places I have checked:

- https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy
- [setting request headers in selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15645093/setting-request-headers-in-selenium)
- [How to use browsermob with python-selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48201944/how-to-use-browsermob-with-python-selenium)
- [setting request headers in selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15645093/setting-request-headers-in-selenium)

And many more...