# Capturing JSON data from intermediate events using Selenium

Tags: python, json, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Below I have setup a script which simply executes a search on a website. The goal is to capture JSON data utilizing Selenium from an event that is fired from an intermediate script, namely the POST request to "https://www.botoxcosmetic.com/sc/api/findclinic/FindSpecialists" as seen in the included image, but without directly sending a request to that URL using Selenium or the requests library. What is the best way to do this, preferably in Python but open to any language?

```py
from selenium import webdriver
base_url = 'https://www.botoxcosmetic.com/women/find-a-botox-cosmetic-specialist'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.find_element_by_class_name('normalZip').send_keys('10022')
driver.find_element_by_class_name('normalSearch').click()
```

[image]

Comment: I think `beautifulsoup` would be more useful for this.

Comment: @demouser123 How would beautifulsoup work for this?

Comment: I think you may be out of luck. As it's not even found in the html source even after the page is rendered

Comment: Why do you need to use Selenium? I feel like you are using the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: @GregBurghardt What would you use instead of Selenium?

Comment: Don't know if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36744627/network-capturing-with-selenium-phantomjs) is a starting point?

Comment: It sounds like you want to intercept the xhr. This is actually pretty convoluted in Selenium.

Comment: @pguardiario if there is another tool that would be easier than Selenium, I'm all for it.

Comment: Puppeteer makes it easy, but it's Javascript not Python.

Comment: @ikemblem If I understand your query correctly, you don't want to use the direct api call using request module. I have the solution to get the information with request module, but wanted to check if that's what something you are interested in.

Comment: You could inject javascript and override xhr methods [see there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26917962/2498790)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to use a proxy, my suggestion would be to use the BrowserMob Proxy.

First of all install the BrowserMob Proxy libraries:

```
pip install browsermob-proxy
```

You will then need to download the [latest release](https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy/releases/download/browsermob-proxy-2.1.4/browsermob-proxy-2.1.4-bin.zip) (2.1.4 at the time of writing this), extract it and then place it in your project directory.  This is going to be a location you need to pass in when setting up the BrowserMob Proxy server (See below where `Server("browsermob-proxy-2.1.4/bin/browsermob-proxy")` is defined)

I've then updated your script to the following:

```
import json

from browsermobproxy import Server
from haralyzer import HarParser
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

base_url = 'https://www.botoxcosmetic.com'
server = Server("browsermob-proxy-2.1.4/bin/browsermob-proxy")
server.start()
proxy = server.create_proxy()

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--proxy-server={0}".format(proxy.proxy))

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
driver.get("{0}/women/find-a-botox-cosmetic-specialist".format(base_url))

proxy.new_har(options={"captureContent": "true"})
driver.find_element_by_class_name('normalZip').send_keys('10022')
driver.find_element_by_class_name('normalSearch').click()

WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#specialist-results > div")))

har_parser = HarParser(proxy.har)
for entry in har_parser.har_data["entries"]:
    if entry["request"]["url"] == "{0}/sc/api/findclinic/FindSpecialists".format(base_url):
        result = json.loads(entry["response"]["content"]["text"])

driver.quit()
server.stop()
```

This will start up a BrowserMob Proxy instance and capture the response for the `FindSpecialists` network call and store it as JSON in the result variable.

You can then use that to do whatever you want to do with the response.  Apologies if the code is not as clean as you would expect, I'm not a native Pythonista.

Useful references are:

- The BrowserMob Proxy [website](https://bmp.lightbody.net)
- The BroswerMob proxy [source code on Github](https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy)
- The Python [documentation](https://browsermob-proxy-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) for BrowserMob Proxy
- The haralyser [website](https://pypi.org/project/haralyzer/)
- The ChromeDriver [website](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/capabilities)

Comment: if you can please update your code to answer the specific example stated in the question, I can accept your answer

Comment: Updated with a detailed solution to your problem

Comment: Thanks. Excellent answer and a very good reference for anyone else attempting something similar