# Catching a 404 error with Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I'm using Selenium and JUnit with Java and I want to know if a 404 error occurs when opening a new popup by clicking on a link (i'm searching for a thing like assertTrue(selenium.no404error()).

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 25):

You can't test if the HTTP status code is 404. This is explained in [this other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6509628/webdriver-get-http-response-code). The only way is to test for something in the page which can only be in your 404 error page. For instance:

```
assertTrue(driver.getTitle().contains("404"));
```

If you're not sure that your page contains something specific like *404* or *Page not found*. You could generate from the server a special tag code (e.g. a `<meta>` tag in the `<head>` section) and test for it with the `WebDriver`.

Comment: At the person who downvoted this answer: could you explain why?

Comment: Beautiful solution. I was smiling for 5 min. :)

Comment: Answer is good, bad is (no) selenium solution...

Comment: I don't uderstand why selenium cannot access the response headers and make those available.

Comment: Can't do it by running javascript from selenium?