# want to verify http no 4xx or 5xx HTTP responses come back through selenium webdriver

Tags: http, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How to check the this http response in selenium web driver? Is it possible to verify the same?

Comment: did you at least try the scenario where selenium gets to such page? Or more generally: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17657037/catching-a-404-error-with-selenium, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354827/checking-http-status-code-in-selenium and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6509628/webdriver-get-http-response-code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get HTTP Response Code using Selenium WebDriver with Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6509628/how-to-get-http-response-code-using-selenium-webdriver-with-java)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to assert on the status of AJAX requests, then you can  create a Browsermob proxy and use it's REST API to verify each request

Comment: @Pavel  m trying  this                                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
      String output;
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((conn.getInputStream())));
            System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
      while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
   System.out.println(output);

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It work for you :P

```
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
String output;
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((conn.getInputStream())));
System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
 System.out.println(output);}
```

Once done verify the response code(using asserts). Let me know if u still face issue.