# IE11-selenium.common.exceptions.webdriverexception message error 404 not found

Tags: selenium, internet-explorer-11, selenium-iedriver

IE driver causing this error.
It mainly occurs while lopping through nested iframes and executing javascript(driver.execute_script).

Can anyone tell me what does this exception mean?

Comment: Refer this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17657037/catching-a-404-error-with-selenium Does this answer your question?

Comment: can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? From your code, it seems that you want to access an element from within an iframe with JavaScript. Please refer to [this article](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_element_iframe.asp) to get Element in an Iframe.