# Slow Selenium tests when using proxy with BrowserMob

Tags: java, selenium, proxy, selenium-webdriver, browsermob

I am setting up a ChromeDriver using BrowserMob(http://bmp.lightbody.net/) for intercepting HTTP responses.

```
ProxyServer proxyServer = null;
proxyServer = new ProxyServer(9101);
proxyServer.start();

proxyServer.setCaptureContent(true);
proxyServer.setCaptureHeaders(true);

Proxy proxy = proxyServer.seleniumProxy();
proxy.setHttpProxy("localhost:9101");


proxyServer.addResponseInterceptor(new ResponseInterceptor() {

@Override
public void process(BrowserMobHttpResponse response, Har har) {
    if (response.getRawResponse().getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 500) {
                    // do something
                }

            }
        });

DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy);

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "seleniumdrivers/chromedriver.exe");
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--lang=nl");
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
this.driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

When running a Selenium test every page load is extremely slow. Without the proxy it works fine. Anyone knows the reason/ solution for this?

In the log console the following message appears: `jan 10, 2014 12:58:06 PM net.sf.uadetector.datastore.AbstractUpdateOperation isUpdateAvailable
INFO: Can not check for an updated version. Are you sure you have an established internet connection?`
No idea if this is related.
Running Selenium tests on an online website (not local server), which means I have internet connection

Comment: Could be related to issue [BrowserMob Proxy extremely slow when recording HAR file](https://github.com/webmetrics/browsermob-proxy/issues/66). Can you confirm if it's getting stuck on accessing `UserAgentInfo`?

Comment: thanks, while digging into it I noticed it is a network issue. The browser is stuck on calling http://code.jquery.com/ (which is declared as script in html) and returns a timeout when using browsermob.
I am connected to an office network with specific proxy settings. The webapplication I am testing is hosted somewhere inside the office network. Apparently I can't access any online website with the browsermob proxy

Comment: @Charlie, Did you find the solution is for it? I am also stuck with the same problem..I am not able to access any website with browsermob proxy

Comment: @javanoob no actually I didn't find a solution for this