# Protractor: how to analyze all incoming and outgoing HTTP traffic

Tags: javascript, testing, protractor, interceptor

I work on a test case with javascript and protractor.On site is an analysis tool in use, which integrates a pixel to the page and tracks the user behaviour. I try all requests of a web page to intercept and read out the url.

I tried to use a proxy to log alle request, but this did not work. does anybody know how to get the outgoing http get-requests?

Comment: Download FireBug on the client in Firefox: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/

Comment: thanks. maybe my question was a little inaccurate. i need the parameters during running time out of the js code. somethink like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6509628/webdriver-get-http-response-code/9817672#9817672 but in javascript

Comment: You can print the intercepted request in using console.log in the test and see it in the dev tools if you are using chrome