# Get response value from POST with Selenium webdriver

Tags: java, post, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I have a POST request like that:

[image: POST request]

Is there any possibility to get this Response id value by using webdriver. Does Selenium support this yet? I am writing automation test with Java

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get HTTP Response Code using Selenium WebDriver with Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6509628/how-to-get-http-response-code-using-selenium-webdriver-with-java)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Selenium does not expose any API to read the responses, headers etc. And, if you think about it that makes sense since it's a tool to replicate end user's behavior and an end user will not do so.

Answer (score 0):

As Saifur said, this is not supported by Selenium.

The closest you can come to automating this would be to send the post request through a different library and check the response.