# Selenium to get response text (Json)

Tags: java, json, selenium-webdriver, response

Exactly as asked in [Get response value from POST with Selenium webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30896439/get-response-value-from-post-with-selenium-webdriver) , to get GET/POST request response text (Json) like this:

[image: POST request]

Is there any possibility to get this Response text with Selenium Java?

I've also checked the answers from
[Java Selenium get JSON response body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45875611/java-selenium-get-json-response-body), but the problem there is that people posted solutions but without an explanation as to what the problem was and how the solution works.

So once again, is it still true that

> Selenium does not expose any API to read the responses, headers etc.

If not, please explanation what the problem was and how the new solution  would work.

PS, *before marking this question as dup, please check the links I've already included.*