# Selenium-Webdriver when i click something How to post and get response from server

Tags: json, post, selenium-webdriver, getresponse

When I click something on a web page I get a response from the server, but how can I catch and validate that response?

For example if I click the 'Flag' option in my webpage I get the following JSON response, but how can I validate it?

I tried this but it's not showing the full response message:

```
System.out.println(htmlPage.getWebResponse().toString());
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can use rest-assure library to check the server return response.Currently i use rest-assured library to do this.
here is a link from where u will get help.

[How to get HTTP Response Code using Selenium WebDriver with Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6509628/how-to-get-http-response-code-using-selenium-webdriver-with-java)

Answer (score 0):

The problem with using REST tools is that they will only return the response for a **new**, non-interactive request, i.e. **outside** the interactive Selenium flow. This won't give you access to the response for a click that Selenium has **already** initiated, which is most likely what you want.

If what you want to do is automatically capture the **actual** responses for all of the clicks you ask Selenium to do, e.g. upon the Flag, then @noor's link has a higher-rated answer that recommends using a proxy server to capture all requests and responses in a queriable form:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19091306/954442

https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy#using-with-selenium

Using that technique, you will be able to query the **complete** response for the request you want, and you'll have access to all parameters, headers, response codes etc.