# check http status code using nightwatch

Tags: selenium, nightwatch.js

how do I check the HTTP status code using nightwatch.js? I tried

```
  browser.url(function (response) {
     browser.assert.equal(response.statusCode, 200);
  });
```

but of course that does not work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get HTTP Response Code using Selenium WebDriver with Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6509628/how-to-get-http-response-code-using-selenium-webdriver-with-java)

Comment: not duplicate, this question related to nightwatch JS

Answer (score 7):

Actually there is no way yet to get the response status of the page using Selenium (https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/141)

But what you can easily do is require "request" library, make your request to the webpage you want to open in your Selenium tests and validate that response status code equals 200:

```
const request = require('request');

request('http://stackoverflow.com', (error, response, body) => {
    browser.assert.equal(response.statusCode, 200);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
    var http = require("http");
    module.exports = {
      "Check Response Code" : function (client) {
          var request = http.request({
            host: "www.google.com",
            port: 80,
            path: "/images/srpr/logo11w.png",
            method: "HEAD"
          }, function (response) {
            client
            .assert.equal(response.statusCode, 200, 'Check status');
            client.end();
          }).on("error", function (err) {
            console.log(err);
            client.end();
          }).end();
         }
       };
```

Answer (score 3):

Supplementing to Hilarion Galushka's answer: you can use the perform() command from nightwatch to intergrate request and assert into your nightwatch tests.
http://nightwatchjs.org/api/perform.html

For example:

```
module.exports = {
    'test response code': function (browser) {
        browser.perform(done => {
            request('http://stackoverflow.com', function (error, response, body) {
                browser.assert.equal(response.statusCode, 200);
                done()
            });
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the best answer IMO.