# Testing https page response using Nightwatch.js

Tags: https, http-status-codes, nightwatch.js

Ok, so I'm looking to test the https response code of a URL using **Nightwatch.js**.

I've install the npm 'request' package, and successfully tested the response of the URL under test using the following code;

```
var request = require('request');
  request('http://www.google.com', function (error, response, body) {
    if (response.statusCode != 200)
      console.log("error!!!")    
});
```

My problem is '*converting*' this working (request) code into a standard **nightwatch.js** setup, so that if the response code is not a 200 then the test will fail?

At the moment my *nightwatch.js* scripts begin with, for example;

```
module.exports = { 
  'test response code': function (browser) {
    browser
```

and I would like to keep it in a similar format.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of 'check http status code using nightwatch' - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36142331/check-http-status-code-using-nightwatch?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the perform() method from nightwatch: http://nightwatchjs.org/api/perform.html

In the perform block you can write every code you want, you can also youse every assertion library. A simple example, based on yours, could look like this:

```
var request = require('request');
var assert = require('assert')

module.exports = {
    'test response code': function (browser) {
        browser.perform(done => {
            request('http://www.google.com', function (error, response, body) {
                assert.ok(response.statusCode == 200)
                done()
            }) 
        })
    }
}
```