# Python selenium: how find hidden download url?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

The page that I worked on has invisible hidden option button, I used 'EC.element_to_be_clickable'.
This code is working, but this is only button's click and downloading by firefox...
I want to get video's link url.

```
_sDriver = webdriver.Firefox()
_sDriver.get('www.example.com/video')

wait = WebDriverWait(_sDriver, 10)
download_menu = _sDriver.find_element_by_id("download-button")
action = ActionChains(_sDriver)
action.move_to_element(download_menu).perform()

documents = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "sample_video")))
documents.click()
```

my code's result is downloading by firefox, but I want to download using python.
example-

```
subprocess.call('wget {0}'.format(documents_url))
```

how do I get documents's url?
thanks for your help.

Comment: As I know there is no simple way to do it, but you can find some ideas here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6509628/how-to-get-http-response-code-using-selenium-webdriver-with-java

Comment: if you can find this element then see what you have in this element - maybe there is your url and you can simple get it (using selenium, lxml, or standard string functions). But every page is different then there is no one universal solution.

Comment: did you try `wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "sample_video"))).get_attribute('href')`?

Comment: @Adnersson oh, I got it! thanks!