# How to capture the requests using JAVA servlets

Tags: java, http, tomcat, servlets, https

I need to capture all the http/https requests that are going through the browsers of my system using JAVA servlets.

Can I achieve that?

Comment: The very nature of HTTPS is to forbid "capturing" of the clear text request/response outside of the applications performing them. Now maybe you could code some kind of servlet based HTTP-proxy and create custom certificates and fool the browsers by installing them as trusted, but this is no light work, and having it work transparently under HTTPS is nearly (if not entirely) impossible.

Comment: Maybe you'll find jpcap usefull. The description says "jpcap is a set of Java classes which provide an interface and system for network packet capture". See https://sourceforge.net/projects/jpcap/ and https://javatutorial.net/capture-network-packages-java

Comment: use Fiddler or WireShark

Comment: Is there any way to do with servlets for capturing specific requests ??

Comment: @Srinivas B yes, it is. Check my answer.

Comment: As a high-rep user, we expect you to know that [ASAP begging](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/472495) is not acceptable in questions. Please refrain from this, thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6509628/how-to-get-http-response-code-using-selenium-webdriver-with-java#

Answer (score 0):

going through the browsers of my system
You can do this is with an implementation of `ServletRequestListener::requestInitialized(ServletRequestEvent sre)`

The [Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequestListener.html) say:

> `requestInitialized(ServletRequestEvent sre)`
>             Receives notification that a ServletRequest is about to come into scope of the web application.

The class could look like this:

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

import javax.servlet.ServletRequestEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequestListener;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebListener;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

@WebListener
public class RequestListener implements ServletRequestListener {
    public RequestListener() {}

    public void requestDestroyed(ServletRequestEvent sre)  {}

    public void requestInitialized(ServletRequestEvent sre)  {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) sre.getServletRequest();

        System.out.println("Timestamp: " + new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        System.out.println("SessionId: " + request.getSession(false));
        System.out.println("RequestURL: " + request.getRequestURL());
        System.out.println("Method: " + request.getMethod());

        System.out.println("Parameters: ");
        for (Entry<String, String[]> entry : request.getParameterMap().entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " = " + Arrays.asList(entry.getValue()));
        }
    }
}
```

In the console you get something like this:

> Timestamp: 2017-01-25 19:12:04.36
>   SessionId: null
>   RequestURL: https://localhost:8181/jee6/ResponseFilterTest/Fiz
>   Method: GET
>   Parameters:
>   p1 = [v1]
>   p2 = [v2]

Instead in the console you can store the data in a DB or write to a log.

If you need to differentiate between local and remote requests you can use `request.getRemoteAddr()`. For local requests it is `127.0.0.1`