# How to capture all the HTTP requests of a URL using java?

Tags: java, http

Just like the F12 of chrome, how can I get all the http requests of URL.
Such as if you F12 in chrome of URL <[How to capture the requests using JAVA servlets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41851231/how-to-capture-the-requests-using-java-servlets)>
You can see it has over 100 requests in the network tab, any way in Java that can get the name list of the requests?

Comment: You want to access this information from Chrome? Or you want to build a kind of proxy to intercept the requests? Or you are making requests from your Java code? Totally unclear.

Comment: I want to get the requests from Java code then I can crawl them in my Java code. Thx