# Getting 401-UnAuthorized Error while validating image/link using Standard Java HttpUrlConnection

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am newbie to selenium webdriver. I am trying to validate broken images/links

### Scenario:

1. Take any sample url from any secured application which is located at different domain.  Ex - footer link – Stores link : `https://username:password@sample.com/some/linkOrimageUrl`
2. Execute the above url using the below code in java.

   URL url = new URL(LnkOrImgurl);
   HttpURLConnection httpURLConnect= HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
   httpURLConnect.setConnectTimeout(3000);
   httpURLConnect.connect();
   message = ""+httpURLConnect.getResponseMessage();
   System.out.println(message);
   httpURLConnect.disconnect();
3. Checking the http response code – `200 – SUCCESS or 401 – UNAUTHORIZED`
4. Expected http response code - `200`

But it throws me always 401- error when i execute this piece of code. Am i doing something wrong here?

Comment: Is there any proxy issue?

Comment: Following link may help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6509628/how-to-get-http-response-code-using-selenium-webdriver-with-java

Comment: @abu - I tried same with apache client to validate with authenticated proxy. But no luck.
HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost("165.225.104.32",80);
Credentials credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials("C_LBaharulislam","welcome1");
AuthScope authScope = new AuthScope("165.225.104.32", 80);
CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
credsProvider.setCredentials(authScope, credentials);
HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().setProxy(proxy).setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider).build();
HttpResponse response=client.execute(new HttpGet(LnkOrImgurl));