# How do i get network status (request/responce) for a webpage using java/javascript

Tags: javascript, java, html, selenium

I am trying to automate a web page using selenium web-driver and would like to know if there is any way to get the network request/response status for a web page ? (or if any network interaction is happening in the page)

I am expecting a similar solution as we get the document ready status using "document.readyState", which will return document status as "Interactive", "Complete", etc..

Comment: Maybe this answers your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6509628/how-to-get-http-response-code-using-selenium-webdriver-with-java

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get HTTP Response Code using Selenium WebDriver with Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6509628/how-to-get-http-response-code-using-selenium-webdriver-with-java)

Comment: Thanks @dcalap, so this says it is not possible to get the network status. in that case, can you please tell me if the other option is possible (check if any network interaction is happening in the page). any hint towards this would be really helpful to me.