# How to get the response content in selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

When I open the URL with `driver.get(url)`, how can I get the response content of the page? Please refer to the image for more information.
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get HTTP Response Code using Selenium WebDriver with Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6509628/how-to-get-http-response-code-using-selenium-webdriver-with-java)

Comment: my question is different with that one

Comment: Can you please elaborate what is your exact testing step? What worked for you? Show code. Share the relevant HTML DOM as well. Thanks

Comment: @Dev There is a token in this page,I want to get the token when I open this page with driver.get(url), then the token text will be used for login

Comment: How does pattern of the token looks like? e.g. Any matching patterns?

Answer (score -1):

In a separate post I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6509628/how-to-get-http-response-code-using-selenium-webdriver-with-java)  answer. As per it there is a ticket opened for Selenium.

Comment: that question is no help for me

Answer (score -1):

I'm using Python and Django, but it's actually simple to get the response. I'm using a `StaticLiveServerTestCase` as my base test for the test. The `.get()` method on `self.client` actually returns the response itself. For example:

```
response = self.client.get(url)
```

However, it looks like what you're really trying to get is the cookie based on what you're pointing to in the picture. I use Django and the Django test suite to authenticate a user session to be used in the test.

```
def create_pre_authenticated_session(self, username, url="/"):
    user = User.objects.create(username=username)
    session = SessionStore()
    session[SESSION_KEY] = user.pk
    session[BACKEND_SESSION_KEY] = settings.AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS[0]
    session[HASH_SESSION_KEY] = user.get_session_auth_hash()
    session.save()

    # to set a cookie we need to first visit the domain.
    # 404 pages load the quickest!
    self.browser.get(self.live_server_url + '/404_no_such_url/')
    self.browser.add_cookie(dict(
        name=settings.SESSION_COOKIE_NAME,
        value=session.session_key,
        secure=False,
        path='/',
    ))
    self.browser.get(self.live_server_url + url)
    return user
```

This has some other stuff in it that I borrowed from Percival's *Test-Driven Development with Python*, but I hope that it can provide some guidance on what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: WebDriver.get(url) does not return a response, it returns 'None'.

Comment: @BryanGreen, I have fixed my response. It turns out I was using `StaticLiveServerTestCase` which has its own `self.client` that returns the response from the browser.