# How to know if the page is offline or not responding?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, python-requests

I've wrote a simple code in Python that browse a few web pages stored in tuple. The goal is to regularly browse those pages and check if they are online and responding. Sample code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

browser = webdriver.Chrome()

links = ('https://stackoverflow.com/', 'https://stackexchange.com/')

while True:
    for url in links:
        try:
            browser.get(url)
            print('OK')
        except Exception as e:
            print('Not OK: {}'.format(e))
```

But this code prints 'OK' even when I am offline, so I guess the get() method doesn't handle any exception if the actual page is not reached.

I've thought about using `WebDriverWait(browser, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'some_common_id')))`
to check if I have reached the actual page but my tuple may contain different url addresses with no common ID, class or element...

Then I thought about reversing this and using `WebDriverWait(browser, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'main-frame-error')))`
to search for a specific element you get in Google Chrome when offline (on their "Dino game" page).
But in this case the script would have to wait for 5 seconds every time the page from my tuple is reached successfully which would unnecessarily slow down the whole test.

I think there has to be a simpler way to browse a page with selenium and know if it is actually reached but I haven't been able to find a solution yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your *usecase* is to know if the page is offline or not responding you don't even need *Selenium* and you can simply use the `requests.head()` method from [**`python-requests`**](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/) as follows:

- Code Block:

  ```
  import requests
  links = ['https://stackoverflow.com/', 'https://stackexchange.com/'] 
  for link in links:
      print(requests.head(link))
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  <Response [200]>
  <Response [200]>
  ```

**Note**: As per the current implementation, *Selenium* when invoking `get()` method actually uses *python-requests* module too.

Comment: Thank you, this works for my usecase. As the requests.head() returns Response object the code itself can be accessed by requests.head(link).status_code.

Answer (score -1):

Selenium doesn't provide module to get http status code. Therefore, you need to use another module such as `request` module. Here is the similar question.

[How to get HTTP Response Code using Selenium WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6509628/how-to-get-http-response-code-using-selenium-webdriver)