# How to get the response status code with selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome

As a newbie, I wonder whether there is a method to get the http response status code to judge some expections, like remote server down, url broken, url redirect, etc...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get HTTP Response Code using Selenium WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6509628/how-to-get-http-response-code-using-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: You need to use another library for it. Check out the requests library in python.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### In Selenium it's Not Possible!

For more info click [here](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/141).

You can accomplish it with `request`:

```
import requests
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.get("url")
r = requests.get("url") 
print(r.status_code)
```

Comment: Why even use selenium then ?

Comment: @VipinJoshi selenium is used for automation testing, assuming the site is up indeed... if you do need to check for the status code you can use `requests` and put the automation in an `if` statement something like `if(requests.get("url").status_code == 200)`

Comment: It is widely used for scraping too, and lots of websites block you detecting user behaviour. Requests just does not emulates the way selenium does, thus not useful for scraping applications. 

I get it, the question wasn't asked in context to scraping stuff.

Comment: @VipinJoshi yes selenium is used for scraping too, but as you can see in the issue that was opened in GitHub >"We will not be adding this feature to the WebDriver API as it falls outside of our current scope (emulating user actions)" see more of the discussion [here](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/141)

Answer (score 1):

Update:
It actually is possible using the chrome-developer-protocoll with event listeners.

See example script at https://stackoverflow.com/a/75067388/20443541