# How after clicking the button to intercept a get-request using selenium python?

Tags: python, selenium, http, selenium-webdriver, get

I want to programmatically get a get-request that appears in chrome devtools(network) after clicking on the "play audio" button. Get-request will enter the page with the audio source.
How can this be implemented on python using selenium ?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible with Selenium under the current build. You can find more information under this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52855435/how-to-get-the-response-status-code-with-selenium). You can achieve it with [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) if you don't have to interact with any javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Possible using request interception with Chrome-Developer-Protocoll.

Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/75067388/20443541