# How to get HttpClient returning status code?

Tags: java, httpclient

I'm developing my first java software as project, using what i learned from the college :'(

i'm trying to transform this website that students using it to get results...to a software,

sorry, the website is in french language, use google to translate the page

url: https://www2.inscription.tn/ORegMx/servlet/AuthentificationEtud?ident=cin

if you notice there's =cin, i still didn't learned php ,but, i think it can do something
i don't know how to use java with http requests, so i did it this way
but i need to know how to get the status code to know if it's 200 so the connection succeed and the inputs are correct and the user is connected 
and if another code so there's an error

```
WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
driver.get("https://www4.inscription.tn/ORegMx/servlet/AuthentificationEtud");

WebElement cin = driver.findElement(By.name("cin"));
WebElement date = driver.findElement(By.name("dn"));
WebElement captcha = driver.findElement(By.name("cincap"));

String cinValue=CIN.getText();
String dateValue=daten.getText();
String captchaValue=captcha.getText();

cin.sendKeys(cinValue);
date.sendKeys(dateValue);
captcha.sendKeys(captchaValue);

captcha.submit();
```

also there's a captcha in the login form in the website, so i'm thinking about using jTextPane as little browser window (still don't know how to do it) to show the captcha so the user will know what to write

I'm using eclipse with windowbuilder pro

valid http request

```
Request URL: https://www4.inscription.tn/ORegMx/servlet/AuthentificationEtud?ident=cin
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: 196.203.190.21:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=Windows-1256
Date: Sat, 19 Jan 2019 21:02:02 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: fr-TN,fr;q=0.9,fr-FR;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.6,ar;q=0.5
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 79
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cookie: JSESSIONID=EEA86798B29324667FE8560D0CEB61FC; __utmc=186433398; __utmz=186433398.1547866934.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); __utma=186433398.482680440.1547866934.1547923662.1547930591.8; __utmt=1; __utmb=186433398.8.10.1547930591
Host: www4.inscription.tn
Origin: https://www4.inscription.tn
Referer: https://www4.inscription.tn/ORegMx/servlet/AuthentificationEtud?ident=cin
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36
ident: cin
cin: xxxxxxxx
dn: xx/xx/xxxx
cincap: b2mb
inscription: valider
etablissement: -1
```

this is the html response page

```
<html><!-- InstanceBegin template="/Templates/standard.dwt" codeOutsideHTMLIsLocked="false" -->
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=Windows-1256">
<!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="doctitle" -->
    <title>Dashboard - Inscription universitaire en ligne</title>

<!-- InstanceEndEditable -->

<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
    <link href="/ORegMx/css/style_jsp.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="/ORegMx/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="/ORegMx/css/params.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="/ORegMx/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <script language="javascript" src="/ORegMx/scripts/cin_verif.js"></script>

<script language="javascript">
    function Inscrire_cin(form) {
        if (!is_cin(form,0)) {
            window.alert("LE N° DE CIN SAISI EST INCORRECT");
        } else {
            form.submit()
        }
    }

</script>
<!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="head" -->
<script language="javascript" src="/ORegMx/jscript/etud.js"></script>

<!-- InstanceEndEditable -->


<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-2629522-5']);
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', '.inscription.tn']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>



</head>

<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" topmargin="2">


<link type="text/css" href="/ORegMx/header.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="top">
    <div id="top_content">

        <div id="top1"><p><img border="0" src="/ORegMx/images/ministere.png"></p></div>

        <div id="top2">
            <a target="_blank"  href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.inscription.tn%2F&amp;t="><img alt="Facebook" src="/ORegMx/images/wpzoom24/facebook.png"></a>
            <a target="_blank" href="http://twitter.com/share?text=&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.inscription.tn%2F"><img alt="Twitter" src="/ORegMx/images/wpzoom24/twitter.png"></a> 
            <!--  <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="/ORegMx/images/wpzoom24/rss.png" alt="Rss"></a>  --> 
        </div>


    </div>
</div>

<div class="content">
    <div id="under_top">

        <div id="logo"><p><a href="/"> <img border="0" alt="logo inscription" src="/ORegMx/images/logo.png"></a></p></div>

    </div>
</div>




<table width="762" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="troisbords">

        <tr> 
          <td valign="top"><!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="principale" -->
            <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
              <!--DWLayoutTable-->
              <tr>
                <td valign="top">
                    <table width="90%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" class="troisbords">

                      <tr>
                        <td height="18" >








                          <TABLE align=center bgColor="white" border=0 cellPadding=5 
            cellSpacing=1 width="100%">
                            <tr>
                              <td align="right"><a style="text-decoration:none" href="/ORegMx/quitter.jsp" class="texte"><h4 class="logout">Déconnexion</h4></a></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>

                        <table>
                        <tr>
                        <td>
                        <div id="banner">
                            <div id="Bleft">&nbsp;</div>
                            <div id="Bmiddle">
                                <div class="moduletable">

                                    <table border="0" width="810" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                    <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                         <div class="parmCase">
                                            <h3>Nom & Pr&eacute;nom</h3>
                                            <p>USER_NAMEXXX&nbsp;</p>
                                         </div>
                                        </td>

                                        <td align="right">
                                         <div class="parmCase" style="float:right">
                                            <h3> الإسم و اللقب </h3>
                                            <p>&nbsp;</p>
                                         </div>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>

                                    <tr class="tow">
                                        <td>
                                         <div class="parmCase">
                                            <h3>Etablissement</h3>
                                            <p>INSTITUT SUPERIEUR DES ETUDES TECHNOLOGIQUES DE SFAX</p>
                                          </div>
                                        </td>

                                        <td align="right">
                                         <div class="parmCase" style="float:right">
                                            <h3>المؤسسة الجامعية</h3>
                                            <p>المعهد العالي للدراسات التكنولوجية صفاقس</p>
                                         </div>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>

                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan="3" align="center"><a class="valid_cin" class="texte" href="/ORegMx/quitter.jsp">Déconnexion</a></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                    </table>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div id="Bright">&nbsp;</div>
                        </div>
                      </td>
                      </tr>

                      </table>

                        <blockquote style="display: none;"/>
                          <p>Dans cet espace vous pouvez proc&eacute;der directement au paiement des frais d'inscription (<a href="/ORegMx/ListeInscriptions.jsp?Idsession=E90ECF9E6654E56AD13B19533ECB79A8&urlRetour=paiement" class="menulink" >
                            <img src="/ORegMx/images/carte_edinar.gif" width="29" height="14" border="0"></a>), consulter et mettre &agrave; jour vos donn&eacute;es personnelles (<a href="#" class="menulink" onclick=submitAction('toInfoPerson','E90ECF9E6654E56AD13B19533ECB79A8') >
                            <img src="/ORegMx/images/ORegMx/navbar1.gif" alt="Gestion des étudiants" width="18" height="18" border="0"></a>) et afficher les re&ccedil;us de vos paiements pass&eacute;s (
                            <a href="#" class="menulink" onclick="submitAction('goRecu','E90ECF9E6654E56AD13B19533ECB79A8')">
                                <img src="/ORegMx/images/ORegMx/navbar14.gif" alt="Inscriptions" width="17" height="19" border="0"></a>). 
                                Vous pouvez aussi acc&eacute;der &agrave; la liste des r&eacute;sultats(<a href="#" class="menulink" onClick="submitAction(" gorecu="" E90ECF9E6654E56AD13B19533ECB79A8>
                                <img width="17" height="19" border="0" src="/ORegMx/images/haut_parleur.jpg" alt="Inscriptions"></a>).<br>
                            <br>
                          </p>
                        </blockquote>

                        <FORM name="form"  method="POST" action="/ORegMx/servlet/AuthentificationEtud">
                            <input type="hidden" name="action1" >
                            <input type="hidden" name="cin" value="xxxxxxxx">
                            <input type="hidden" name="Idsession" value="E90ECF9E6654E56AD13B19533ECB79A8">
                            <input type="hidden" name="typeAction" value="nouv_inscription">


                        <div class="bureau_box">
                        <table border="0" width="100%">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="mbox">
                                <div class="sub-hero-ionic-adidas" style="text-align: center;">
                                    <span class="sub-text-wrapper">
                                        <a href="/ORegMx/ListeInscriptions.jsp?Idsession=E90ECF9E6654E56AD13B19533ECB79A8&urlRetour=paiement">
                                        <i class="fa fa-credit-card-alt icon-fa-dashoboard" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
                                        <br>
                                        <!--  h4>Paiement</h4-->                                        
                                            <p class="sub-shop-button">Paiement
                                                <!--  i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i -->
                                            </p>
                                        </a>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="mbox">
                                <div class="sub-hero-ionic-adidas" style="text-align: center;">
                                    <span class="sub-text-wrapper">
                                        <a href="#" onclick="submitAction('toInfoPerson','E90ECF9E6654E56AD13B19533ECB79A8')">
                                        <i class="fa fa-user-circle icon-fa-dashoboard" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                        <br>
                                        <!--  h4>Informations</h4 -->                                       
                                            <p class="sub-shop-button">Informations</p>
                                        </a>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="mbox">
                                <div class="sub-hero-ionic-adidas" style="text-align: center;">
                                    <span class="sub-text-wrapper">
                                        <a href="#" onclick="submitAction('toCarteEtd','E90ECF9E6654E56AD13B19533ECB79A8')">
                                        <i class="fa fa-id-card-o icon-fa-dashoboard" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                        <br>
                                        <p class="sub-shop-button">Carte Etudiant</p></a>
                                        <a href="#" onclick="submitAction('toCarteEtd2','E90ECF9E6654E56AD13B19533ECB79A8')">&nbsp;</a>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="mbox">
                                <div class="sub-hero-ionic-adidas" style="text-align: center;">
                                    <span class="sub-text-wrapper">
                                        <a href="#" onclick="submitAction('goResultat','E90ECF9E6654E56AD13B19533ECB79A8')">
                                        <i class="fa fa-graduation-cap icon-fa-dashoboard" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                        <br>
                                        <!--  h4>Résultats</h4 -->                                      
                                        <p class="sub-shop-button">Résultats
                                                <!--  i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i -->
                                            </p>
                                            </a>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="mbox">
                                <div class="sub-hero-ionic-adidas" style="text-align: center;">
                                    <span class="sub-text-wrapper">
                                        <a href="#" onclick="submitAction('toOffice365','E90ECF9E6654E56AD13B19533ECB79A8')">
                                        <i class="fa fa fa-globe icon-fa-dashoboard" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                        <br>
                                        <!--  h4>Votre compte office 365</h4-->
                                        <p class="sub-shop-button">Office 365
                                                <!--  i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i-->
                                            </p>
                                            </a>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="mbox">
                                <div class="sub-hero-ionic-adidas" style="text-align: center;">
                                    <span class="sub-text-wrapper">
                                        <a href="#" onclick="submitAction('goRecu','E90ECF9E6654E56AD13B19533ECB79A8')">
                                        <i class="fa fa-print icon-fa-dashoboard" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                        <br>
                                        <!--  h4>Vous avez 1 reçus (+0 archive)</h4-->
                                            <p class="sub-shop-button">Mes Reçus</p> <br>
                                            <p>(1 reçus (+2 archive))
                                                <!--  i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i--></p>
                                        </a>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        </table>
                        </div>






                        </FORM>
                        <p>

                        </p>

                         </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  <br>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          <!-- InstanceEndEditable --></td>
        </tr>

<link type="text/css" href="/ORegMx/footer.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="content">   
        <table border="0" align="center">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>

</div> 
<div id="footer">
  <p>Copyright &copy; Minist&egrave;re de l'Enseignement Sup&eacute;rieur et de la Recherche Scientifique - Tunisie</p>
</div>
<div align="center">  <p>      <span class="texte"> 
                            <a href="http://www.progress.com.tn" target="_blank" ><img src="/ORegMx/images/powered.gif" width="110" height="30" border="0"></a><br>
                            Portail bas&egrave; sur un produit de <a href="http://www.progress.com.tn" target="_blank" >Progress Engineering</a>
                            </span> </p>
        </div>

        <tr valign="middle"> 
          <td height="40"> <div align="center" class="texte">
          <!-- #BeginLibraryItem "/Library/performance.lbi" --><div align="center">

  Requ&ecirc;te trait&eacute;e en  <b>16</b> millisecondes / Page g&eacute;n&eacute;r&eacute;e en <b>0</b> millisecondes</div>
<!-- #EndLibraryItem --></div></td>
        </tr>
      </table></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
<!-- InstanceEnd --></html>
```

Comment: i managed to use page title to check if the user connected or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WebDriver API does not provide access to the HTTP status. There is a lengthy post about the reasons and options to get this information at [How to get HTTP Response Code using Selenium WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6509628/how-to-get-http-response-code-using-selenium-webdriver)

You can use the WebDriver API to inspect the result after your submit call. Look for meta tags and page elements unique to error pages at this website. With findElement calls you can ensure their existence within the result page.

In this particular case the server just seems to deliver the same form again. You can reuse your calls from above.

Within your result page of a valid login you can find a logout link by its class name "logout". If the webdriver cannot find that element, your login attempt failed.

```
    try {
      WebElement logout = driver.findElement(By.className("logout"));
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
      // you are not logged in
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, really appreciate it, what you suggest, continue in this code or using another way ?

Comment: I do not know how a valid response page of this form looks like. Can you please provide an example?

Comment: i added it in the post, hope that what you mean, thanks

Comment: I need to see the HTML source of the result page. The HTTP header you added looks good, but you need page elements to identify.

Comment: HTML of the response added, please check if it's correct, thanks

Comment: Thank you very much sir

Comment: I just learned about seleniumwire and its ability to access http headers with selenium: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54456944/how-to-know-if-my-custom-http-headers-are-being-passed