# How to find Chrome Webdriver's status-code?

Tags: python, http-status-codes, google-chrome-headless

Is it possible to receive the status code of a URL with headless Chrome (python)?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6512785/10854709) answer it's not possible using python and selenium (I guess you are using selenium?).
A working alternative from selenium and chrome is [requests](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/). With requests an example would look like this:

```
import requests
response = requests.get('https://api.github.com')
print(response.status_code)
```