# How to catch HTTP request of python selenium web driver?

Tags: django, selenium, selenium-webdriver, httprequest, chrome-web-driver

I am making a web application with Django-Gunicorn-Nginx. It is a kind of closed community. Therefore at the start of sign-up, authentication by the third-party server is required. Because the third-party server does not provide official auth API, I'm trying to implement module by my self with python selenium.

I have built the module in a python file in Django accounts app directory. When I test the module with the terminal by `python3 somemodulename.py`, it works perfectly. However, when I import the module(which is a function) in `view.py` of the accounts app and test with browser, at some point, the third-party app throws an `invalid session` message. It never happened when I test exactly the same function with the terminal.

So, if there is any way to catch HTTP request that selenium chrome web driver sends, I would like to compare both cases for debugging. How could one get the full HTTP request of Chrome web driver with python selenium, without interfering the process of code?

I am sorry that I could not append the actual code because of the security issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible using Selenium APIs. A long and boring discussion on why can be found [here](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/141).

However, there are few workarounds, for example, you can try capturing it using the browser logs. A good example of how to do it is discussed here: 
[How to get HTTP Response Code using Selenium WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6509628/how-to-get-http-response-code-using-selenium-webdriver).