# How I could obtain the Id token bearer using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, testing, browser-automation

How I could obtain the id token bearer after login using selenium webdriver or maybe another framework?
Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: what is id token bearer?

Comment: A simple id token bearer after login (OAuth2 authentication). I need some library that extract that informacion.

Comment: You could try looking at the network responses: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6509628/how-to-get-http-response-code-using-selenium-webdriver

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're referring to OAuth2 authentication.

For that you don't need to use Selenium webdriver, but create an API client using RestSharp or some other API library.
You probably have an internal authentication server with exposed endpoint, which you need to contact and supply username, password, grant_type, scope, client_id and maybe few other parameters, depending on your authentication server (please refer to documentation)

Then make a request, parse JSON and voila - you have a token.