# getHeader from getInternalResponse in Symfony Panther always return an empty array

Tags: php, symfony, testing, symfony-panther

By using Symfony Panther, I sent a request and I wanted to get the response. I was able to get the body and the status code but for the header I just got an empty array.

```
$client = Client::createChromeClient();
$client->request('GET', 'https://google.com');
$client->getInternalResponse()->getHeaders(); // returned empty array!!!
```

Comment: I get the same. I tried `$client->getResponse()` also, but that is not allowed.

Answer (score 2):

Panther does not have access to the HTTP response as explained in this github issue https://github.com/symfony/panther/issues/17.

But if you read carefuly, you'll see that this is not a limitation of Panther but a limitation of Selenium WebDriver. See this post [How to get HTTP Response Code using Selenium WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6509628/how-to-get-http-response-code-using-selenium-webdriver).

**This means that the answer to the question "Can I have access to the HTTP response code or the HTTP header using Symfony Panther?" is "No, it's not possible".**

While this is not possible the workaround I found was to create an `HttpClient` and use it to make a request and get the response from it.

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\HttpClient\HttpClient;

$client = HttpClient::create();
$response = $client->request('GET', $this->myBaseUri);
$statusCode = $response->getStatusCode();
$headers = $response->getHeaders();
```

Here's the documentation for [HTTP Client (Symfony Docs)](https://symfony.com/doc/current/http_client.html) if you want to try this way.

Answer (score 0):

According to this issue: https://github.com/symfony/panther/issues/67, it seems that status code is not managed ( HTTP 200 will always get returned, no matter what the request actually responded.)

And same for the headers, I'm afraid. If you look at class
`Symfony\Component\Panther\Client` and method `get($url)` you can see that:

`$this->internalResponse = new Response($this->webDriver->getPageSource());`

while Response's constructor accepts:

`public function __construct(string $content = '', int $status = 200, array $headers = [])`

Having these said, no matter what happens, you always get HTTP 200 and empty header array.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Client::createChromeClient()`
you can use the following code

```
$statusCode = $client->executeScript('return window.performance.getEntries()[0].responseStatus');
```