# Detect for 500 server error as a "active listener" using Selenium and C#

Tags: c#, selenium-chromedriver

So I have done some research and can not find anything on this topic specifically so I am not sure if it is possible.

I am writing automated testing for an application, and under specific situations I will get 500 server errors. Rather than looking for the text on the page to say that it encountered a server 500 error, I want to do this reviewing network requests.

Ideal situation would be to have some sort of listener for when a 500 error occurs during a test, that the test will automatically fail and let me know that a 500 error occurred.

I have been doing research and can not find anything on this topic specifically, so if anyone has resources for me to point to or an example of them doing this that would be amazing!

Thank you

Comment: Is Selenium the right tool for the job, though? AFAIK, Selenium is a UI automation tool, so it will help you **precisely** looking at "some text on the page", as opposed to directly checking the network requests. For the latter I would expect other kinds of tests such as Postman tests. But I'm not sure. See this: [How to get HTTP Response Code using Selenium WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6509628/how-to-get-http-response-code-using-selenium-webdriver). Spoiler: it's not possible at worst, or it's not straightforward at best.