# How to detect when Selenium loads a browser's error page

Tags: firefox, selenium, htmlunit

Is there a universal way to detect when a selenium browser opens an error page? For example, disable your internet connection and do

```
driver.get("http://google.com")
```

In Firefox, Selenium will load the 'Try Again' error page containing text like "Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at www.google.com." Selenium will NOT throw any errors.

Is there a browser-independent way to detect these cases?  For firefox (python), I can do

```
if "errorPageContainer" in [ elem.get_attribute("id") for elem in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("body > div") ]
```

But (1) this seems like computational overkill (see next point below) and (2) I must create custom code for every browser.

If you disable your internet and use htmlunit as the browser you will get a page with the following html

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>Unknown host</body>
</html>
```

How can I detect this without doing

```
if driver.find_element_by_css_selector("body").text == "Unknown host"
```

It seems like this would be very expensive to check on every single page load since there would usually be a ton of text in the body.

Bonus points if you also know of a way to detect the type of load problem, for example no internet connection, unreachable host, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[WebDriver API doesnot expose HTTP status codes](http://jimevansmusic.blogspot.com.au/2013/08/implementing-webdriver-http-status.html) , so if you want to detect/manage HTTP errors, you should use a debugging proxy.

See Jim's excellent post [Implementing WebDriver HTTP Status](http://jimevansmusic.blogspot.com.au/2013/08/implementing-webdriver-http-status.html) on how to do exactly that.

Comment: Thank you. Do you happen to know if adding a proxy like this can interfere with tor?

Comment: @user2426679: I haven't worked with tor, so unfortunately no ideas about that.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to remote-control the Tor Browser, you might also consider the [Marionette](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Marionette) framework by Mozilla. Bonus: **It fails when a page cannot be loaded**: ([see navigate(url) in the API](http://marionette-client.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference.html#marionette))

> The command will return with a failure if there is an error loading
>   the document or the URL is blocked. This can occur if it fails to
>   reach the host, the URL is malformed, the page is restricted (about:*
>   pages), or if there is a certificate issue to name some examples.

Example use (copy from [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32568990)):

To use with the Tor Browser, enable marionette at startup via

```
Browser/firefox -marionette
```

(inside the bundle). Then, you can connect via

```
from marionette import Marionette
client = Marionette('localhost', port=2828);
client.start_session()
```

and load a new page for example via

```
url='http://mozilla.org'
client.navigate(url);
```

For more examples, there is a [tutorial](http://marionette-client.readthedocs.org/en/latest/basics.html).