# How to initiate a Tor Browser 9.5 which uses the default Firefox to 68.9.0esr using GeckoDriver and Selenium through Python

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, geckodriver, tor

I'm trying to initiate a tor browsing session through *Tor Browser 9.5* which uses the default *Firefox v68.9.0esr* using [GeckoDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43660195/why-firefox-requires-geckodriver/43661697#43661697) and [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) through Python on a [windows-10](/questions/tagged/windows-10) system. But I'm facing an error as:

[image: tor_firefoxESR]

Code Block:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile
import os

torexe = os.popen(r'C:\Users\username\Desktop\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Tor\tor.exe')
profile = FirefoxProfile(r'C:\Users\username\Desktop\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Browser\profile.default')
profile.set_preference('network.proxy.type', 1)
profile.set_preference('network.proxy.socks', '127.0.0.1')
profile.set_preference('network.proxy.socks_port', 9050)
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.socks_remote_dns", False)
profile.update_preferences()
firefox_options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
firefox_options.binary_location = r'C:\Users\username\Desktop\Tor Browser\Browser\firefox.exe'
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile= profile, options = firefox_options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\geckodriver.exe')
driver.get("https://www.tiktok.com/")
```

Where as the same code block works through Firefox and Firefox Nightly using the respective binaries.

Do I need any additional settings? Can someone help me out?

---

**Firefox Snapshot**:

[image: tor_firefox]

---

**Firefox Nightly Snapshot**:

[image: tor_firefoxNightly]

Answer (score 2):

I managed to resolve this by updating to v9.5.1 and implementing the following changes:

*Note that although the code is in C# the same changes to the Tor browser and how it is launched should be applied.*

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile(profilePath);
profile.SetPreference("network.proxy.type", 1);
profile.SetPreference("network.proxy.socks", "127.0.0.1");
profile.SetPreference("network.proxy.socks_port", 9153);
profile.SetPreference("network.proxy.socks_remote_dns", false);

FirefoxDriverService firefoxDriverService = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService(geckoDriverDirectory);
firefoxDriverService.FirefoxBinaryPath = torPath;
firefoxDriverService.BrowserCommunicationPort = 2828;
var firefoxOptions = new FirefoxOptions
{
    Profile = null,
    LogLevel = FirefoxDriverLogLevel.Trace
};
firefoxOptions.AddArguments("-profile", profilePath);
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxDriverService, firefoxOptions);
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com");
```

Important notes:

The following TOR configs need to be changed in **about:config** :

- **marionette.enabled**: true
- **marionette.port**: set to an unused port, and set this value to **firefoxDriverService.BrowserCommunicationPort** in your code. This was set to 2828 in my example.

Comment: I don't think the issue is with **marionette** here. _GeckoDriver_ works through _marionette_ only. Moreover, no ports are occupied on my test machine.

Comment: They weren't on mine either, and yet they didn't work before I explicitly set these configs. Give it a try :)

Comment: Hello, can you send me the Python code? This is only C#? Because I can't find the Module "FirefoxDriverService" in Python. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, there is only C# code, I do not know Python well unfortunately. However, the selenium library should provide similar functionality perhaps the classes are named differently

Answer (score 1):

**note**: 
I am not sure whether this really is the definite answer (thus, I'd really appreciate feedback)

**solution**:
I've managed to send a get request to the check tor page (https://check.torproject.org/) and it displayed an unknown IP to me (additionally, IPs differ if you repeat the request after a time)

Essentially, I've set up the chrome driver to run TOR. Here's the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

tor_proxy = "127.0.0.1:9150"

chrome_options = Options()

chrome_options.add_argument("--test-type")
chrome_options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
chrome_options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
chrome_options.add_argument("--incognito")
chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=socks5://%s' % tor_proxy)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)


driver.get('https://check.torproject.org/')
```

Because the driver is not in headless mode you can inspect the resulting page yourself. It should read: 
*"Congratulations. This browser is configured to use Tor. [IP Info]. However, it does not appear to be Tor Browser. Click here to go to the download page"*

Make sure that the chromedriver.exe file is linked on the path or provide the path to the file as an argument to the driver.Chrome() function.

**Edit:** make sure TOR browser is running in the background, thanks @Abhishek Rai for pointing that out

Comment: You need to have Tor Browser running...beforehand for this to work.

Comment: Happy to hear it worked & yes, TOR has to run in the background, thanks for pointing out!

Do you know if really all traffic is running through TOR in this setup though @AbhishekRai? ... or at least how to properly check for that?

Comment: I simply set the opening url as wtfismyip.com ..No other reason for it to show my IP as German, I', in India...So, I'm guessing it works. It changes the IP after a while as well. Just doesn't say using a Tor Exit node.