# Opening Tor in Selenium giving error when opening browser

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

When I try opening Tor with selenium I get an error when tor opens saying "Tor failed to start."
The only other post online with a similar problem that I found is: [Selenium error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62666075/how-to-initiate-a-tor-browser-9-5-which-uses-the-default-firefox-to-68-9-0esr-us)

I also have geckodriver on my machine already.

My code looks like the following:

```
from selenium import webdriver    
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

    binary = FirefoxBinary(r"D:\Tor Browser\Browser\firefox.exe")
    profile = FirefoxProfile(r"D:\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Browser\profile.default")
    profile.set_preference('network.proxy.type', 1)
    profile.set_preference('network.proxy.socks', '127.0.0.1')
    profile.set_preference('network.proxy.socks_port', 9150)
    profile.set_preference('network.proxy.socks_remote_dns', 'False')
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile, binary)
```

[image]

Comment: are you using windows ?

Comment: Yes I'm using windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TO open tor you can use :

https://github.com/webfp/tor-browser-selenium

**Steps:**

**First goto tor browser and type about:profiles :**

[image]

**THen open Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Tor folder :**

There you can see a tor.exe file double click that :

[image]

**Then run below code**

```
from tbselenium.tbdriver import TorBrowserDriver
import time
driver= TorBrowserDriver(executable_path=r"C:\Users\prave\Downloads\travelBA\geckodriver.exe", tbb_fx_binary_path=r'C:\Users\prave\Desktop\Tor Browser\Browser\firefox.exe', tbb_profile_path=r'C:\Users\prave\Desktop\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Browser\profile.default')
driver.get('check.torproject.org')
time.sleep(100000)
```

**Note:** if you get a error saying filenotfound blabla/browser create an empty folder named broser at that location

Comment: Do I need the tbselerium for this to work?

Comment: Yes , tor is a new system  that is build on firefox you cannot directly use firefox profile

Comment: This seemed to work :). Having a different issue now but not related to this post.

Comment: You can use this to open chrome using tor.proxy but it works only for incognito mode

Comment: can I ask you a question? Why do I need to make a folder named browser? Currently I needed to make 20 folders browser one inside each other because I loop through a list and every time I need a new one. Is there a way to disable this?

Comment: Logs are generated inside that folder , I don't think you need 20 folders only one would be enough

Comment: When I make a loop it says Browser/Browser doesn't exist. And when I loop again it says Browser/Browser/Browser doesn't exist