# How can I disable javascript in puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, puppeteer

I am trying to disable javascript so that websites know that the javascript is disabled on puppeteer (ie: `<noscript>` tags) in a base class made to crawl websites however my script fail to so as it's not disabling javascript when I go to any websites.

Here is my code:

```js
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39134419/run-tor-browser-with-selenium-webdriver
import puppeteer, { puppeteerErrors, Target, Browser } from "puppeteer";
import { readFileSync } from "fs"
import { helpers } from "./helpers";
import _ from "lodash"

/**
 * Base class for all crawler
 */
abstract class BaseCrawler {
  public static readonly TOR_PATH = process.env.TOR_PATH ?? "";
  public static readonly TOR_PROFILE_PATH = process.env.TOR_PROFILE_PATH ?? "";
  public static readonly TORRC_PATH = process.env.TORRC_PATH;
  public static headless = false
  public readonly browser: Promise<puppeteer.Browser>;
  private readonly jsEnabled: boolean;

  /**
   * get the active page
   * @returns null if it couldn't get the active
   */
  public async activePage(timeout = 30_000): Promise<puppeteer.Page | null> {
    const browser = await this.browser;
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    while (new Date().getTime() - start < timeout) {
      var pages = await browser.pages();
      var arr = [];
      for (const p of pages) {
        if (await p.evaluate(() => { return document.visibilityState == 'visible' })) {
          arr.push(p);
        }
      }

      if (arr.length == 1)
        return arr[0];
    }
    return null;
  }

  constructor(jsEnabled = false, website = "https://google.com") {
    console.log(Browser)
    
    this.browser = puppeteer.launch({
      headless: BaseCrawler.headless,
      //args: ["--proxy-server=socks5://127.0.0.1:9050"],
      userDataDir: "./.headless-data"
    });

    this.jsEnabled = jsEnabled;
    this.browser.then(async (b) => {
      b.on("targetcreated", async (e: Target) => {

        const page = await e.page();
        // set a tor useragent
        page?.setUserAgent(`Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/${_.random(60, 100)}.0`);

        // disable script if it's aksed
        if (page?.url()) {
          // console.log(page.url().search("chrome://"))
          if (page.url().search("chrome://") < 0)
            page?.setJavaScriptEnabled(this.jsEnabled)
        }

        page?.on('request', request => {
          if (request.resourceType() === 'script')
            request.abort();
          else
            request.continue();
        })
      })
    })

    this.browser.then(async (b) => {
      b.newPage()
      const page = await b.newPage();
      page.goto(website);
    })
  }
}
/** Bland tor window just made to browse tor */
export class TorWindow extends BaseCrawler {
};
```

I tried to hook the `newPage` function however it doesn't work as it's giving me the following error:

```
PS C:\Users\vince\project\js\crawler-project> yarn run browser
yarn run v1.22.10
$ node . --tor-window
undefined
C:\Users\vince\project\js\crawler-project\\dist\Crawler.js:35
        const old_newpage = puppeteer_1.default.Browser.prototype.newPage;
                                                        ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
    at new BaseCrawler (C:\Users\vince\project\js\crawler-project\dist\Crawler.js:35:57)
    at new TorWindow (C:\Users\vince\project\js\crawler-project\dist\Crawler.js:98:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\vince\project\js\crawler-project\dist\index.js:27:5)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1092:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1121:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:972:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:813:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:76:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

```js
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39134419/run-tor-browser-with-selenium-webdriver
import puppeteer, { puppeteerErrors, Target, Browser } from "puppeteer";
import { readFileSync } from "fs"
import { helpers } from "./helpers";
import _ from "lodash"

/**
 * Base class for all crawler
 */
abstract class BaseCrawler {
  public static readonly TOR_PATH = process.env.TOR_PATH ?? "";
  public static readonly TOR_PROFILE_PATH = process.env.TOR_PROFILE_PATH ?? "";
  public static readonly TORRC_PATH = process.env.TORRC_PATH;
  public static headless = false
  public readonly browser: Promise<puppeteer.Browser>;
  private readonly jsEnabled: boolean;

  /**
   * get the active page
   * @returns null if it couldn't get the active
   */
  public async activePage(timeout = 30_000): Promise<puppeteer.Page | null> {
    const browser = await this.browser;
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    while (new Date().getTime() - start < timeout) {
      var pages = await browser.pages();
      var arr = [];
      for (const p of pages) {
        if (await p.evaluate(() => { return document.visibilityState == 'visible' })) {
          arr.push(p);
        }
      }

      if (arr.length == 1)
        return arr[0];
    }
    return null;
  }

  constructor(jsEnabled = false, website = "https://check.torproject.org") {
    console.log(Browser)
    const old_newpage = puppeteer.Browser.prototype.newPage
    puppeteer.Browser.prototype.newPage = async () => {
      const page = await old_newpage()
      page.setJavaScriptEnabled(this.jsEnabled)
      return page;
    }
    this.browser = puppeteer.launch({
      headless: BaseCrawler.headless,
      args: ["--proxy-server=socks5://127.0.0.1:9050"],
      userDataDir: "./.headless-data"
    });

    this.jsEnabled = jsEnabled;
    this.browser.then(async (b) => {
      b.on("targetcreated", async (e: Target) => {

        const page = await e.page();
        // set a tor useragent
        page?.setUserAgent(`Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/${_.random(60, 100)}.0`);

        // disable script if it's aksed
        if (page?.url()) {
          // console.log(page.url().search("chrome://"))
          if (page.url().search("chrome://") < 0)
            page?.setJavaScriptEnabled(this.jsEnabled)
        }

        page?.on('request', request => {
          if (request.resourceType() === 'script')
            request.abort();
          else
            request.continue();
        })
      })
    })

    this.browser.then(async (b) => {
      b.newPage()
      const page = await b.newPage();
      page.goto(website);
    })
  }
}
/** Bland tor window just made to browse tor */
export class TorWindow extends BaseCrawler {
};
```

Comment: You should indeed use `page.setJavaScriptEnabled(false)` to disable javascript, and the error isn't connected to that; I suggest you start with a simpler example.

Comment: I notice that chromium ask me if it should really disable javascript(https://i.imgur.com/jAYHVAO.png).This might be why I wasn't able to disable javascript.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the following:

```
page.setJavaScriptEnabled(false)
```

Set this before navigating to the website.

More information to read on this you can find at:
[page.setJavaScriptEnabled(enabled)](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v8.0.0&show=api-pagesetjavascriptenabledenabled)

Comment: Is there a way I can bind that each time a page is created so I don’t have to do it every time.

Comment: You have to reuse the se page or set each individual time the page is created.

Answer (score 2):

[`Page.setJavaScriptEnabled(value)`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v11.0.0/docs/api.md#pagesetjavascriptenabledenabled) returns a `Promise` so you need to `await` it. Also according to the docs:

> NOTE changing this value won't affect scripts that have already been run. It will take full effect on the next navigation.

```
await page.setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

> To disable javascript, we need to monitor all the requests/responses flowing. Then based on the type, we can decide to terminate the request/response.

> In the below example, we will load flipkart.com without using the javascript files.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
(async() => {
const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setRequestInterception(true);
  page.on('request', request => {
    if (request.resourceType() === 'script')
      request.abort();
    else
      request.continue();
  });
  await page.goto('https://www.flipkart.com');
  await browser.close();
  })();
```

source: https://chercher.tech/puppeteer/disable-javascript-puppeteer

If you know that website will serve page without js for certain crawlers, you can try change headers.

Comment: Will the website detect that js is disabled? ie: `<noscript>` tag working

Comment: This doesn't work as I want the website to know that js is disable through the `<noscrpt>` tag