# Error while launching TOR browser with Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, tor

I'm using Selenium 2.53.0 Java, Tor 6.0.4 and Firefox 43. I'm executing tor with firefox by loading the profile.default archive with the Firefoxprofile() and a Firefoxbinary() with firefox.exe. Tor launchs, but it doesn't initiate, it shows two errors:  Could not connect to Tor control port and Tor failed to start.

I've followed this post to [Using Selenium WebDriver with Tor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22978074/using-selenium-webdriver-with-tor) to set up the Firefox driver.

See below the code. Thanks!

```
String torPath = "C:\\Users\\Jose Bernhardt\\Desktop\\Tor Browser\\Browser\\firefox.exe";
    String profilePath = "C:\\Users\\Jose Bernhardt\\Desktop\\Tor Browser\\Browser\\TorBrowser\\Data\\Browser\\profile.default";

    File torProfileDir = new File(profilePath);
    FirefoxBinary binary = new FirefoxBinary(new File(torPath));
    FirefoxProfile torProfile = new FirefoxProfile(torProfileDir);
    FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(binary, torProfile);
```

These are the Exceptions thrown:

```
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary(C:\Users\Jose Bernhardt\Desktop\Tor Browser\Browser\firefox.exe) on port 7055; process output follows
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because you are using a wrong version of firefox driver

try below :

```
public WebDriver driver;
system.setproperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","path to your firefoxdriver");
driver = new FierfoxDriver();
```