# Change user-agent for Selenium web-driver

Tags: python, selenium, http-headers, user-agent

I have the following code in `Python`:

```
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
from contextlib import closing

with closing(Firefox()) as browser:
  browser.get(url)
```

I would like to print the user-agent HTTP header and
possibly change it. Is it possible?

Answer (score 222, accepted):

There is no way in Selenium to read the request or response headers. You could do it by instructing your browser to connect through a proxy that records this kind of information.

#### Setting the User Agent in Firefox

The usual way to change the user agent for Firefox is to set the variable `"general.useragent.override"` in your Firefox profile. Note that this is independent from Selenium.

You can direct Selenium to use a profile different from the default one, like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("general.useragent.override", "whatever you want")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
```

#### Setting the User Agent in Chrome

With Chrome, what you want to do is use the `user-agent` command line option. Again, this is not a Selenium thing. You can invoke Chrome at the command line with `chrome --user-agent=foo` to set the agent to the value `foo`.

With Selenium you set it like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
opts = Options()
opts.add_argument("user-agent=whatever you want")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=opts)
```

Both methods above were tested and found to work. I don't know about other browsers.

#### Getting the User Agent

Selenium does not have methods to query the user agent from an instance of `WebDriver`. Even in the case of Firefox, you cannot discover the default user agent by checking what `general.useragent.override` would be if not set to a custom value. (This setting does not *exist* before it is set to some value.)

Once the browser is started, however, you can get the user agent by executing:

```
agent = driver.execute_script("return navigator.userAgent")
```

The `agent` variable will contain the user agent.

Comment: Note that I have `from selenium.webdriver import Firefox`. I'm trying to figure out, how to set the profile for `Firefox`, I imported from `selenium.webdriver`.

Comment: user-agent is not request or response header, but it is general header.

Comment: I deal with Firefox in my answer in the first code snippet. Also, `User-Agent` absolutely **is** a request header. See [section 14.43](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html): "The User-Agent **request-header field** contains information about the user agent originating the request." (Emphasis mine.)

Comment: OK, I combined it with my code. So, for setting user-agent is there a set_preference method. Is there something like get_preference as well, to know what it was before?

Comment: You're right, it is a request-header field. In the book HTTP essentials (page 56) is mistake.

Comment: I've edited my answer with a section about one way to get the user agent.

Comment: Nice. This was very helpful. I added an answer for how to do this in PhantomJS too.

Comment: So we MUST change the profile to change the user agent string? the reason i'm asking is because i need to maintain the session to avoid having to log in for every single instance i create

Comment: I do it but my browser (FF) is under remote controller yet. Is it correct?

Comment: There is a problem with this method that "Firefox Profile - Cannot open window as TAB.“  https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/1139

Comment: Btw call me a newbie, though "whatever you want" is a bit misleading lol. I literally put a random string and well, didn't realise that there was more to it. Finally got a proper glimpse of the structure from here https://intoli.com/blog/making-chrome-headless-undetectable/

Answer (score 24):

This is a short solution to change the request UserAgent on the fly.

**Change UserAgent of a request with Chrome**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.setUserAgentOverride', {"userAgent":"python 2.7", "platform":"Windows"})
driver.get('http://amiunique.org')
```

then return your useragent:

```
agent = driver.execute_script("return navigator.userAgent")
```

**Some sources**

The source code of *webdriver.py* from SeleniumHQ (https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/11c25d75bd7ed22e6172d6a2a795a1d195fb0875/py/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py) extends its functionalities through the Chrome Devtools Protocol

```
def execute_cdp_cmd(self, cmd, cmd_args):
        """
        Execute Chrome Devtools Protocol command and get returned result
```

We can use the Chrome Devtools Protocol Viewer to list more extended functionalities (https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network#method-setUserAgentOverride) as well as the parameters type to use.

Comment: This would be useful when I want to change the user agent on __every__ request, but not the whole driver session

Answer (score 19):

To build on Louis's helpful answer...

#### Setting the User Agent in PhantomJS

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
...
caps = DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS
caps["phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent"] = "whatever you want"
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(desired_capabilities=caps)
```

The only minor issue is that, unlike for Firefox and Chrome, this does *not* return your custom setting:

```
driver.execute_script("return navigator.userAgent")
```

So, if anyone figures out how to do that in PhantomJS, please edit my answer or add a comment below! Cheers.

Comment: I do it but this massage is published when I run it:
http.client.RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response

Answer (score 11):

Firefox Profile is deprecated, you have to use it in Firefox options like this:

```
opts = FirefoxOptions()
opts.add_argument("--headless")
opts.add_argument("--width=800")
opts.add_argument("--height=600")
opts.set_preference("general.useragent.override", "userAgent=Mozilla/5.0 
(iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 15_4 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like 
Gecko) CriOS/101.0.4951.44 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1")
```

Answer (score 0):

To build on JJC's helpful answer that builds on Louis's helpful answer...

With PhantomJS 2.1.1-windows this line works:

```
driver.execute_script("return navigator.userAgent")
```

If it doesn't work, you can still get the user agent via the log (to build on [Mma's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47533387/7227370)):

```
from selenium import webdriver
import json
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

dcap = dict(DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS)
dcap["phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent"] = (UserAgent().random)
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=r"your_path", desired_capabilities=dcap)
har = json.loads(driver.get_log('har')[0]['message']) # get the log
print('user agent: ', har['log']['entries'][0]['request']['headers'][1]['value'])
```

Comment: Hi,
Could you tell me what's your mean from "your_path" in this part:
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=r"your_path", desired_capabilities=dcap)

Comment: I guess you want to say address of "phantomjs.exe" in "bin file".

Comment: I do it but, this massage will be published for me:
http.client.RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response

Comment: I do it but I can't see any change in browser is "under remote control" mood. Can you analyze it?