# How to make chromedriver undetectable

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

This is my first Stack Overflow question so please bear with me.

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225947/can-a-website-detect-when-you-are-using-selenium-with-chromedriver/41904453#41904453) SO question, which lead me to wondering, is it possible to make chromedriver completely undetectable?

For my own curiosity's sake I have tested the method described and found that it was unsuccessful in creating a completely anonymous browser.

I read through the driver's documentation and found this:

> `partial interface Navigator {
>        readonly attribute boolean webdriver;
>     };`
>
> The webdriver IDL attribute of the Navigator interface must return the value    of the webdriver-active flag, which is initially false.
>
> This property allows websites to determine that the user agent is under control by WebDriver, and can be used to help mitigate denial-of-service attacks.

However, I cannot find where these tags are even located through the browser console or in the source code.

I would imagine this is responsible for the detection of chromedriver, however, after combing through the source code, I could not find this interface. As a result, it has left me wondering whether or not this feature is included in the current chromedriver. If not, I still know that the current chromedriver is detectable by websites and other services such as [distill](https://www.distilnetworks.com/).

Comment: What are you trying to do, exactly? Create an "anonymous" user agent or to make ChromeDriver to act as a "regular" Chrome browser? And what are the actual problems you've run into?

Comment: By definition chromedriver is a "regular" chrome browser. It utilizes a JSON Wireframe Protocol sending messages to a "real" chrome browser. However, what's interesting to note is that it is certainly detectable as a selenium webdriver. I want to clean this detection out of the browser to create what servers would see as a real authentic browser. This way I can customize my current browser to my exact liking without fear of websites thinking I am trying to perform a DDOS attack, and restricting me from their website as a result.

Comment: <in clippy's voice> I think you are trying to launch a DDOS attack. Let me help you! -- in reality websites detect bots using far more complex techniques than detecting the selenium.

Answer (score 35):

In order to use ChromeDriver undetectable to Distil checkpoints (which are described nicely in this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225947/can-a-website-detect-when-you-are-using-selenium-with-chromedriver)), you will need to ensure that your browser does not contain any variable in its window or document prototypes that reveal that you are using a webdriver, as the one you mention.

You can use software as Selenium along with ChromeDriver and Chrome as long as you take some precautions and make some fixes to the binaries. This method will apply only to headed version, if you wish to use headless, you would need to take additional measurements to pass window/rendering tests, [described here](https://intoli.com/blog/making-chrome-headless-undetectable/).

---

**1. Fix Chrome binary, or use an old version**

First, lets deal with that `navigator.webdriver` set to True. This
    is defined by W3C protocol [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#dom-navigatorautomationinformation) as part of
    'NavigatorAutomationInformation' of browsers, which extends the Navigator
    interface. How to remove it? That project has a lot of files, third party stuff, blink web runtimes, etc. So, instead of becoming crazy trying to figure out how this works, as Chromium is open-source, just be clever and search google for the commit which incorporated that. [Here is the link](https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/c/chromium/src/+/665978). Pay attention to these files:

- `third_party/WebKit/Source/core/frame/Navigator.h`, which holds the line of code:

  ```
   `bool webdriver() const { return true; }` 

  This method is supossed to always return true, as you can see.
  ```
- `third_party/WebKit/Source/core/frame/Navigator.idl`, which contains the extensions of Navigators, included our

  ```
  `Navigator implements NavigatorAutomationInformation;` 

  which is being commited. Interesting, isn't it?
  ```
- `third_party/WebKit/Source/core/frame/NavigatorAutomationInformation.idl` contains the extension itself, with a read-only variable, which is `webdriver`:

  ```
       `[
           NoInterfaceObject, // Always used on target of 'implements'
           Exposed=(Window),
           RuntimeEnabled=AutomationControlled
       ] interface NavigatorAutomationInformation {
           readonly attribute boolean webdriver;
       };`
  ```

To get rid of this functionality, it should be enough commenting the line in `Navigator.idl` which extends `Navigator` with this functionality, and compile the source ([compiling in linux here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/lkcr/docs/linux_build_instructions.md)). However, this is a laborious task for almost any computer and can take several hours. If you look the date of the commit, it was on **Oct 2017**, so an option is to download **any version of Chrome released before that date**. To search for mirrors, you can google for `inurl:/deb/pool/main/g/google-chrome-stable/`.

---

**2. Fix ChromeDriver**

Distil checks the regex rule '/\$[a-z]dc_/' against window variables, and ChromeDriver adds one as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225947/can-a-website-detect-when-you-are-using-selenium-with-chromedriver) which satisfies that condition. As they mention, you have to edit `call_function.js` amongst the source code, and redefine the variable `var key = '$cdc_asdjflasutopfhvcZLmcfl_';`. with something else. Also, probably easier, you can use an hex editor to update the existing binary.

If you decided to use an older version of Chrome -I guess you did-, you will need to use an appropiate version of ChromeDriver. You can know which one is fine for your Chrome version in the [ChromeDriver downloads webpage](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads). For example, for Chrome v61 (which fits your needs), you could use [ChromeDriver 2.34](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.34/). Once done, just put the ChromeDriver binary on '/usr/bin/local'.

---

**3. Take other precautions**

- Pay attention to your user-agent.
- Don't perform too many repeated requests.
- Use a (random) delay between requests.
- Use the Chrome arguments used [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225947/can-a-website-detect-when-you-are-using-selenium-with-chromedriver) to mimic a normal user profile.

Comment: For the additional measures a user of Chrome headless has to take - that you shared from the itoli link, https://intoli.com/blog/making-chrome-headless-undetectable/ - they seem to be written to work through the use of a proxy, using the `mitmproxy` Python module. Is there a way to apply those javascript-injected settings without using that module or a proxy?

Comment: Just as an fyi for anyone looking to do this; Chromium no longer uses WebKit; they use "blink".  The files you are looking for are in third_party/blink/renderer/core/frame now.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use Selenium's WebDriver itself to change UserAgent, which sounds like what you're really trying to do here.

However, that doesn't mean it can't be changed.

*Enter PhantomJS.*

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41678604/2172566). You can use that to disguise Selenium as a different browser, or pretty much anything else. Of course, if a website is determined to figure you out, there are plenty of clues that Selenium leaves behind (like clicking with perfect precision).

Comment: Hi, and thank you for your response. If you are to open a chromedriver, and regular chrome browser, and compare the two, you'll notice that the browser headers look exactly the same. (Unless I was doing it wrong. I used http://www.whoishostingthis.com/tools/user-agent/ for this check).