# Selenium is not loading TikTok pages

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm implementing a TikTok crawler using selenium and scrapy

```
start_urls = ['https://www.tiktok.com/trending']
....
def parse(self, response):
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    from fake_useragent import UserAgent
    ua = UserAgent()
    user_agent = ua.random
    options.add_argument(f'user-agent={user_agent}')
    options.add_argument('window-size=800x841')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
    driver.get(response.url)
```

The crawler open Chrome but it does not load videos.
[Image loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zFWv.png)

The same problem happens also using Firefox 
[No loading page using Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vw5AF.png)

The same problem using a simple script using Selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time


driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.tiktok.com/trending")
time.sleep(10)
driver.close()

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.tiktok.com/trending")
time.sleep(10)
driver.close()
```

Comment: Does it work when using Selenium from outside Scrapy?

Comment: The problem persists using a simple python script using Selenium

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/pywebview/

Comment: I personally found the solution of zebo to be working

Comment: all of you saying you found it working, can you provide a link to the code you used?

Answer (score 3):

Did u try to navigate further within the selenium browser window? If an **error 404** appears on following sites, I have a solution that worked for me:

I simply changed my User-Agent to "*Naverbot*" which is "allowed" by the robots.txt file from Tik Tok

([Robots.txt](https://www.tiktok.com/robots.txt))

After changing that all sites and videos loaded properly.

Other user-agents that are listed under the "allow" segment should work too, if you want to add a rotation.

Comment: can you show with code please? been having trouble getting fake-useragent to load in VS code

Comment: @wesleyfranks check out this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29916054/change-user-agent-for-selenium-driver) on how to set user-agents in Selenium. For me changing it to "Googlebot" or "Naverbot" does the job!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Windows IE](https://selenium.dev/downloads/). Instead of chrome or firefox

Videos will load in IE but IE's Layout of showing feed is somehow different from chrome and firefox.

> Reasons, why your page, is not loading.

Few advance web apps check your browser history, profile data and cached to check the authentication of the user. 
One other thing you can do is run your default profile within your selenium It would be helpfull.

Comment: Can't use IE in ubuntu.

Comment: There are only two things working right now. 1- Selenium with an app called "Multilogin". 2 - The drawrowfly's GitHub repo.

Comment: @ZeeshanAhmad does the page open as mobile browser only?