# How can I change user agent in selenium remote web driver

Tags: c#, asp.net, selenium-grid, selenium-remotedriver

I will use selenium remote web driver for test my web application.
In my case I should be use firefox web driver.
Now I don't know how canI change my useragent in this case

It is my code for use remote web driver

```
DesiredCapabilities Capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
Capabilities.SetCapability(CapabilityType.BrowserName, "firefox");                
string GridURL = "http://localhost:4545/wd/hub";
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri(GridURL), Capabilities);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29916054/change-user-agent-for-selenium-driver

Comment: in this link show how can change user agent in firefox webdriver no in remote webdriver

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly change the `RemoteWebDriver`. [RemoteWebDriver c# Documentation](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Remote_RemoteWebDriver.htm). From the documentation, you can see that the RemoteWebDriver is an abstraction of more concrete implementations like `FirefoxDriver` and `ChromeDriver`.

These imlementations expose preferences like the `user.agent`. What the api is trying to tell you, is that not all `RemoteWebDrivers` need to have preferences and thus it's not part of the class.

You can however do the following since [FirefoxDriver extends RemoteWebDriver](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Firefox_FirefoxDriver.htm)

```
RemoteWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

You can use the `FirefoxProfile` and a `FirefoxDriver`

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.SetPreference("general.useragent.override", "Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 6_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10A5355d Safari/8536.25");
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

[A full example](https://csharp.hotexamples.com/examples/OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox/FirefoxProfile/-/php-firefoxprofile-class-examples.html):

```
public static IWebDriver GetDriver(string driver, Devices device)
 {
     DeviceModel model = Device.Get(device);
     IWebDriver webDriver;
     switch (driver.ToLower())
     {
         case "safari":
             webDriver = new SafariDriver();
             break;
         case "chrome":
             webDriver = new ChromeDriver();
             break;
         case "ie":
             webDriver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
             break;
         //case "firefox":
         default:
             var profile = new FirefoxProfile();
             profile.SetPreference("general.useragent.override", model.UserAgent);
             webDriver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
             webDriver.Manage().Window.Size = model.ScreenSize;
             break;
     }
     return webDriver;
 }
```

Comment: i will change user agent in remoter webdriver no in firefox webdriver!!!!

Comment: You can't. https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Firefox_FirefoxDriver.htm firefox driver extends remote web driver. Check the documentation, the remote web driver has nothing to expose the profile.

Comment: By the way, you are using RemoteWebDriver when you use FirefoxDriver. You can even assign the FirefoxDriver to a RemoteWebDriver without casting.