# How to make selenium as undetectable as possible

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have been working on using selenium and pyton on a website recently, and it seems to know I am using selenium. I have tried using chromdriver, geckodriver, using headless browsers, using random delays, and a few other methods. Does anyone know of any other methods that would work?

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: Change the user agent
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29916054/change-user-agent-for-selenium-web-driver

Comment: I have tried changing the user agent and sadly that still has not worked.