# How to grab headers in python selenium-webdriver

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to grab the headers in selenium webdriver. Something similar to the following:

```
>>> import requests
>>> res=requests.get('http://google.com')
>>> print res.headers
```

I need to use the `Chrome` webdriver because it supports flash and some other things that I need to test a web page. Here is what I have so far in Selenium:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://login.comcast.net/login?r=comcast.net&s=oauth&continue=https%3A%2F%2Flogin.comcast.net%2Foauth%2Fauthorize%3Fclient_id%3Dxtv-account-selector%26redirect_uri%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Fxtv-pil.xfinity.com%2Fxtv-authn%2Fxfinity-cb%26response_type%3Dcode%26scope%3Dopenid%2520https%3A%2F%2Flogin.comcast.net%2Fapi%2Flogin%26state%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Ftv.xfinity.com%2Fpartner-success.html%26prompt%3Dlogin%26response%3D1&reqId=18737431-624b-44cb-adf0-2a85d91bd662&forceAuthn=1&client_id=xtv-account-selector')
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#user').send_keys('XY@comcast.net')
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#passwd').send_keys('XXY')
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#passwd').submit()
print driver.headers ### How to do this?
```

I have seen some other answers that recommend running an entire selenium server to get this information (https://github.com/derekargueta/selenium-profiler). How would I get it using something similar to the above with Webdriver?

Comment: Could you please elaborate what headers do you want to extract and what for? Thanks.

Comment: Pretty sure that you cannot do it out of the box.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Unfortunately, you **cannot** get this information from the Selenium webdriver, nor will you be able to any time in the near future it seems. An excerpt from [a very long conversation on the subject](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/141):

> This feature isn't going to happen.

The gist of the main reason being, from what I gather from the discussion, that the webdriver is meant for "driving the browser", and extending the API beyond that primary goal will, in the opinion of the developers, cause the overall quality and reliability of the API to suffer.

One potential workaround that I have seen suggested in a number of places, including the conversation linked above, is to use [BrowserMob Proxy](https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy), which can be used to capture HTTP content, and [can be used with selenium](https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy#using-with-selenium) - though the linked example does not use the Python selenium API. It does seem that there is [a Python wrapper for BrowserMob Proxy](https://github.com/AutomatedTester/browsermob-proxy-py), but I cannot vouch for it's efficacy since I have never used it.

Comment: what about executing javascript or something within the page to log it to console or something? Is there a (hackish) way to do something like that?

Comment: One suggestion I have seen repeatedly on this subject is to use BrowserMob Proxy: https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy, which can be used with selenium: https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy#using-with-selenium. However, I do not have experience with this utility. Sorry I couldn't be of more help!

Comment: @David542 also, see the last paragraph of my updated answer. It includes a link to a Python wrapper for BrowserMob Proxy, which may work for your use case.

Answer (score 7):

Now,  it is very easy i suppose https://pypi.org/project/selenium-wire/
it is an extension of selenium. use `from seleniumwire import webdriver` and proceed as usual.

Comment: I wish this was more popular & updates still being rolled out, it's so intuitive ...

Answer (score 5):

You could try [Mobilenium](https://github.com/rafpyprog/Mobilenium), a python package (still in development) that binds BrowserMob Proxy and Selenium.

An usage example:

```
>>> from mobilenium import mobidriver
>>>
>>> browsermob_path = 'path/to/browsermob-proxy'
>>> mob = mobidriver.Firefox(browsermob_binary=browsermob_path)
>>> mob.get('http://python-requests.org')
301
>>> mob.response['redirectURL']
'http://docs.python-requests.org'
>>> mob.headers['Content-Type']
'application/json; charset=utf8'
>>> mob.title
'Requests: HTTP for Humans \u2014 Requests 2.13.0 documentation'
>>> mob.find_elements_by_tag_name('strong')[1].text
'Behold, the power of Requests'
```

Comment: i get an error `ImportError: cannot import name 'mobidriver'`. Any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: @west `pip install mobilenium`

Comment: @West i was wrong, there is an issue with that repo, you can work around it with: `pip install -U git+https://github.com/rafpyprog/Mobilenium`

Answer (score 2):

You can get the header via the log (source from [Mma's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47533387/7227370))

```
from selenium import webdriver
import json
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=r"your_path")
har = json.loads(driver.get_log('har')[0]['message']) # get the log
print('headers: ', har['log']['entries'][0]['request']['headers'])
```

Comment: Where do you put the site url?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JAVASCRIPT built-in method.

It only can be done once the driver has already been created though.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
# Store it in a variable and print the value
agent = driver.execute_script("return navigator.userAgent")
print(agent)
# directly print the value
print(driver.execute_script("return navigator.userAgent"))
```