# get http status code python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, http-status-codes

How can I get the http status code in python if I open a link?
I did it this way, but it always shows 200 even if the page throws a 404 error...

```
from urllib.request import *

self.driver.get(link)
code = urlopen(link).getcode()
if not code == 200: 
  print('http status: ' + str(code))
```

Comment: posible dublicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5799228/how-to-get-status-code-by-using-selenium-py-python-code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the problem, Selenium will always find a page. You have 2 ways to check if loading didn't work :

1 : Check content

```
self.assertFalse("<insert here a string which is only in the error page>" in self.driver.page_source)
```

2 : Use Django test Client

```
response = self.client.get(link)
self.assertEqual(response.status_code,200)
```

Comment: ok thanks, actually I can't get django work...it has some issues with the settings

Comment: If you need some help about it i'm there.

Answer (score 0):

Edited your example.
Try to use requests library.

```
from requests import get

self.driver.get(link)
request = get(link)
if not request.status_code == 200:
  print('http status: ' + str(request.status_code))
```

Hope, this will help you.