# How to check if there is a picture on a website or not with Python and Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I want to check with a boolean request, if there is a picture on the website:

https://portal.dnb.de/opac/mvb/cover?isbn=9783442472352

or not:

https://portal.dnb.de/opac/mvb/cover?isbn=3499239663

I don`t know how that is possible.

Thank you for your help!!

Comment: Does the site you want to inspect always look like this? I.e. is there only one image or is the site unreachable. Can you clarify the logic of the software?

Comment: What have you tried? What problems, errors faced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you should deal with response status - for `selenium`, take a read:

[How to get status code by using selenium.py (python code)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5799228/how-to-get-status-code-by-using-selenium-py-python-code)

Alternative approach, get the `status` with `requests`:

```
import requests
urls = ['https://portal.dnb.de/opac/mvb/cover?isbn=9783442472352','https://portal.dnb.de/opac/mvb/cover?isbn=3499239663']
for url in urls:
    r = requests.get(url)
    if r.status_code == 200:
        print(url, ': yeah, there seems to be an image')
    elif r.status_code == 400:
        print(url, ': nope, no image here')
```

##### Output

```
https://portal.dnb.de/opac/mvb/cover?isbn=9783442472352 : yeah, there seems to be an image
https://portal.dnb.de/opac/mvb/cover?isbn=3499239663 : nope, no image here
```